# Make an error quine!

Tags: popularity-contest, quine, error-message

Your challenge: write a "program", for a language of your choice, that causes the compiler/interpreter/runtime to produce *error output* when compiling/running your program which is identical to your program's source code.

Rules:

- Your program may be specific to a particular version or implementation of your language's compiler/interpreter/runtime environment. If so, please specify the particulars.
- Only standard compiler/interpreter/runtime options are permitted. You cannot pass some weird flag to your compiler to get a specific result.
- The program does *not* need to be syntactically or semantically valid, but I may give a bounty to the best syntactically valid submission.
- The program must not produce any output of its own (e.g. by calling a print or output function). All output generated upon attempting to compile/run the program must originate from the compiler/interpreter/runtime.
- The complete output of the compiler/interpreter/runtime must be exactly identical to your program source code.
- The compiler/interpreter/runtime must generate at least one error message when invoked with your program.

This is a *popularity contest*. Most creative answer, as determined by upvotes, wins. If you can give a *good* case for using a standard loophole, you may do so.

Comment: What is "*error output*"? And what does it mean to "*generate an error message*"? More specifically: 1) Does the output have to be to stderr? 2) If the runtime logs an error to syslog and doesn't write anything to stderr, what should be compared to the source of the program? 3) If the runtime throws an exception internally when given an empty program, but requires a flag to actually print the exception and so ends up exiting with a non-zero exit code but no output, has an error message been generated?

Comment: I tried doing this in java and got a p3 oscilator. This was the shortest phase: (Compile from q.java): `Error: Could not find or load main class Q`

Comment: Ha, because of a syntactic ambiguity in the first sentence, I thought the challenge here was to produce a program which normally produces no output, but if you pass its own code to it as input, it produces an error.

Comment: When reporting an error, APL always prints a customizable error name, optionally an error message, the name of the program that caused the error, the (bracketed) line number where the error occurred, the line of code that caused the error, and a line with a caret indicating where parsing stopped. Any hope for participation here?

Comment: @SteveBennett Why haven't you made that challenge yet?

Comment: It's non-observable whether something is output by the runtime or the program. You could argue that a syntacticly invalid program is actually triggering a built-in function that prints an error message, making rule 4 impossible to fulfill. Is [this](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59WlJ@rUFxZrJCZW5BfVKJlXWyrhEVMtci6oCgzr0SjWFW1WCctMyfVtrgkJbWoSNM6tSKzRMNQUwmuALv8//8A) a valid submission in Python 3?

Comment: I wonder if we can do the same but with warnings instead of errors...

Answer (score 135, accepted):

## Ed (1 byte)

All the other solutions thus far are long and ugly. I suppose that is because of the nature of most error messages. But a good error message is elegant in its simplicity. For that, look no further than ed.

```
?
```

Save this to a file called `edscript` and run with `ed < edscript`, or run `ed<<<?`.  The result:

```
?
```

The question mark is written to stderr and ed returns 1, so this actually is an error message. I wonder why ed isn't very popular?

## False (0 bytes)

Run with `false filename`. It writes the program's source code (i.e. nothing) to stderr and returns 1.  Of course, calling false a programming language is questionable, and the zero byte quine is unoriginal, but I thought I might as well add it.  There is probably some interpreter for a language that prints no error messages, and could replace false.

Now I wish this was code golf.

Comment: I was looking through the (long) list of esolangs to find a language like this. This is the weakness of this challenge. It's not about writing a clever program, it's about cleverly choosing the language. :/

Comment: @IngoBürk Fortunately this is a popularity contest, not a golf.

Comment: The 0-byte False is also the same code that at one time won the "Worst Abuse of the Rules" award by the IOCCC for making the theoretically shortest quinine. It had plenty of compiler errors, though, and it was written in K&R C, not ISO C (which is stricter).

Comment: @IngoBürk Many real-life problems are about cleverly choosing the language, too. :P

Comment: @fluffy Wow, I completely missed that. :) I take back everything I said.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows Quinine?

Comment: @Mendeleev *Quine (Until somewhat recently, I've constantly misread "quine" as "quinine" for some reason...)

Answer (score 154):

### Windows Command Prompt

```
& was unexpected at this time.
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this works with `|` also.

Comment: & was unexpected at this time. +1

Comment: Mind blowing one

Comment: Doesn't work for languages other than english :( Sad

Comment: This should be the winner, not only because it's better than the accepted one IMO, but because it has more upvotes.

Answer (score 87):

### CoffeeScript, syntactically valid

As tested on [their website](http://coffeescript.org/) using Chrome or Firefox.

```
ReferenceError: defined is not defined
```

You can replace `defined` with anything that's not a built-in variable, but I thought this version was fun. Unfortunately, `undefined is not defined` in particular doesn't work as a quine.

In CoffeeScript this isn't even a syntax error, because it compiles. This is technically a runtime error in JavaScript, albeit a boring one. CoffeeScript is a likely candidate to produce some more interesting runtime error quines because a lot of funny sentences are valid code. E.g. the above example compiles to

```
({
  ReferenceError: defined === !defined
});
```

Comment: `defined` is by `defined`ition `defined`. Wha...how...?

Comment: `Undefined is not defined` (with a capital `U`) seems to work lol

Answer (score 73):

## Windows .EXE, 248 bytes

```
The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
```

No, really. Save as `quine.txt`, then rename to `quine.exe` (or download it [here](https://gist.github.com/aaronryank/b11a719bb450718e0d7693b337029344/archive/dbe0ce95ef570a3f2147137382229f0eaa87a19e.zip)):

[image]

Answer (score 55):

## Python

### Spyder

Well, a rather trivial solution for the Spyder IDE is to raise a `SyntaxError`.

**Code and identical output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/falko/golf.py", line 1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(Python 2.7.8 with Spyder 2.2.5)

---

### Terminal

An alternative solution for Python started from command line struggles with an unexpected indent.

**Command:**

```
python golf.py
```

**Code and identical output:**

```
  File "golf.py", line 1
    File "golf.py", line 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

---

### ideone.com

On [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) a solution might be as follows. [(Try it!)](http://ideone.com/sGPFdT)

**Code and identical output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py", line 117, in compile
    raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError: SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('prog.py', 1, 22, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n'))
```

(This is for Python 2. An example for Python 3 is trivial but with [15 lines of "code"](http://ideone.com/mQ7NRI) rather lengthy.)

---

## General approach:

### How to create your own solution in 2 minutes?

1. Open a new file in an IDE of your choice.
2. Bang your head onto the keyboard in front of you.
3. Compile.
4. Replace the code with the compiler error message.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until the code converges.

I bet such a procedure terminates pretty quickly in most cases!

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm using that general approach. It doesn't work when the copied code progressively increases the amount of compiler errors. :-)

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: That's when our much-valued expert knowledge about software engineering is required. ;)

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Or when you are sent off running in circles. Try it in the Excel-VBA immediate window.

Comment: I did step 1, 2, and 3, but I couldn't do step 4, the perl code was perfectly valid!

Comment: Hey how about this in the python stock IDE, `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` produces the same thing too :)

Comment: Prefer the second one because that's straight up Python; no IDE/Framework mess.

Comment: @Falko I've actually used the general approach before lol

Answer (score 47):

### ><> - 25 Bytes

```
something smells fishy...
```

In Fish, any bad instruction outputs the error: "something smells fishy...". Since s is not a valid command, it errors immediately.

Comment: Please note that the language name is ><>, which is usually pronounced "fish".

Comment: And it's really "Something smells fishy..."

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ On the python interpreter, it is indeed `something smells fishy...`, but it is `Something smells fishy...` on the online interpreter. It's dependent on the interpreter.

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE Ah, thanks.

Comment: Cuz 'fish' is the name of the [shell program/language for the 90s](https://fishshell.com/)!

Answer (score 42):

## [Chicken](https://web.archive.org/web/20180816190122/http://torso.me/chicken)

```
Error on line 1: expected 'chicken'
```

Comment: What a peculiar language

Comment: Link to language is dead.

Comment: @pppery Fixed. I should probably get this on TIO.

Comment: waiting for tio addition...

Answer (score 40):

## Whitespace

First I thought this is clearly impossible. But actually it is trivial as well. -.-

```
Fail: Input.hs:108: Non-exhaustive patterns in function parseNum'
```

[Try it.](http://ideone.com/13FBnQ)

Yeah, my first whitespace program! ;)

Comment: Can we even call *this* a whitespace program?

Comment: Is this an interpreter bug?

Answer (score 34):

## JavaScript

Since different browsers use different JavaScript compilers, they produce different messages. These are, however, rather trivial solutions.

### V8 (Chrome 36 / Node.js)

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

[image]

### SpiderMonkey (Firefox 31)

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

[image]

### Chakra (Internet Explorer 11)

```
Expected ';'
```

[image]

Comment: In `jsc`: `Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'identifier'` :D

Comment: @ConfusedMr_C That's a wierd token to choke on.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Yes. At least it works :P

Comment: Is `(f=n=>console.error(\`(f=${f})()\`))()` cheating?

Comment: Spider Monkey! 

Answer (score 34):

### Microsoft Excel

Formula: `#DIV/0!`

Error Message: `#DIV/0!`

In order to enter a formula without using an equals sign, go into Excel Options/Advanced/Lotus Compatibility Settings and enable Transition Formula Entry.

Comment: -2 bytes: `#REF!`

Answer (score 31):

### Commodore 64 Basic

```
?SYNTAX  ERROR
```

When run on the emulator of your choice (or an actual Commodore 64), produces

```
?SYNTAX  ERROR
```

This is, in fact, a syntactically-valid one-line program.  The question mark is a shortcut for `PRINT`, and `SYNTAX` and `ERROR` are valid variable names.  The error occurs because the parser gets confused by the substring `OR` in `ERROR`.

Comment: If the parser gets confused and throws a syntax error, doesn't that make it *not* syntactically valid?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, that really depends on which you consider the authority for "valid syntax": the language description, or the language implementation.

Comment: I see, so technically is syntactically valid but it's tripping up the parser due to a bug of a particular implementation?

Comment: More or less, confounded by the fact that there *is* only one implementation.

Comment: Nitpick: CBM BASIC actually prints two spaces, not one, between "SYNTAX" and "ERROR".  Unfortunately I can't edit this answer to correct it, as Stack Exchange imposes a silly 6-character minimum for edits.

Comment: @Psychonaut, fixed.

Comment: `ERROR` isn't a valid variable name in Commodore BASIC; `ERR` would be.

Answer (score 23):

### Java 8 compilation error quine (12203 bytes)

Generated on windows + mingw with java 1.8.0_11 jdk, using this command:

```
echo a > Q.java; while true; do javac Q.java 2> Q.err; if [ $(diff Q.err Q.java | wc -c) -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; cat Q.err > Q.java; done
```

May not be the shortest one, may not be the longest one either, more a proof of concept. Works because error output shows at most 100 errors.

```
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
^
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                      ^
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                 ^
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                      ^
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Q.java:1: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                           ^
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      ^
Q.java:2: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
       ^
Q.java:2: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        ^
Q.java:2: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
               ^
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                      ^
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                 ^
Q.java:2: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                      ^
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Q.java:2: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                           ^
Q.java:3: error: illegal start of type
^
^
Q.java:4: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
 ^
Q.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
      ^
Q.java:4: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
       ^
Q.java:4: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
        ^
Q.java:4: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
               ^
Q.java:5: error: '(' expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 ^
Q.java:5: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      ^
Q.java:5: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
       ^
Q.java:5: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        ^
Q.java:5: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
               ^
Q.java:5: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                      ^
Q.java:5: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                 ^
Q.java:5: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                      ^
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Q.java:5: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                           ^
Q.java:6: error: illegal start of type
                      ^
                      ^
Q.java:7: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
 ^
Q.java:7: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
      ^
Q.java:7: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
       ^
Q.java:7: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
        ^
Q.java:7: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
               ^
Q.java:8: error: '(' expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 ^
Q.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      ^
Q.java:8: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
       ^
Q.java:8: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        ^
Q.java:8: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
               ^
Q.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                      ^
Q.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                 ^
Q.java:8: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                      ^
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Q.java:8: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                           ^
Q.java:9: error: illegal start of type
                                 ^
                                 ^
Q.java:10: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
 ^
Q.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
      ^
Q.java:10: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
       ^
Q.java:10: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
        ^
Q.java:10: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
               ^
Q.java:10: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                       ^
Q.java:10: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                               ^
Q.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                ^
Q.java:10: error: unclosed character literal
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                  ^
Q.java:10: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                    ^
Q.java:10: error: unclosed character literal
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                       ^
Q.java:10: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                                     ^
Q.java:10: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                                           ^
Q.java:10: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                                                      ^
Q.java:10: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                                                                                 ^
Q.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      ^
Q.java:11: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
       ^
Q.java:11: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        ^
Q.java:11: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
               ^
Q.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                      ^
Q.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                 ^
Q.java:11: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                      ^
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Q.java:11: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                           ^
Q.java:12: error: illegal start of type
                                      ^
                                      ^
Q.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
                                      ^
                                       ^
Q.java:13: error: = expected
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
   ^
Q.java:13: error: ';' expected
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
      ^
Q.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
              ^
Q.java:13: error: = expected
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
               ^
Q.java:13: error: ';' expected
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
                  ^
Q.java:13: error: = expected
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
                               ^
Q.java:13: error: unclosed character literal
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
                                   ^
Q.java:13: error: unclosed character literal
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
                                        ^
Q.java:13: error: = expected
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
                                                          ^
Q.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: = expected
      ^
Q.java:14: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: = expected
       ^
Q.java:14: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: = expected
        ^
Q.java:14: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: = expected
               ^
Q.java:14: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: = expected
                 ^
Q.java:15: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
^
Q.java:15: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 ^
Q.java:15: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      ^
Q.java:15: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
       ^
Q.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        ^
Q.java:15: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
          ^
Q.java:15: error: ';' expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
               ^
Q.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                      ^
Q.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                 ^
Q.java:15: error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                      ^
  (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Q.java:15: error: = expected
Q.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                                           ^
Q.java:16: error: illegal start of type
                                           ^
                                           ^
Q.java:17: error: = expected
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
 ^
Q.java:17: error: <identifier> expected
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
      ^
Q.java:17: error: ';' expected
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
       ^
Q.java:17: error: illegal start of type
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
        ^
Q.java:17: error: = expected
Q.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
               ^
100 errors
```

Answer (score 22):

## Bash (32)

Save as file named `x`:

```
x: line 1: x:: command not found
```

When run:

```
>> bash x
x: line 1: x:: command not found
```

Answer (score 22):

## ArnoldC

```
missing IT'S SHOWTIME on first line
```

Paste the code into [this compiler](http://mapmeld.github.io/ArnoldC/).

Comment: What's funny is that `IT'S SHOWTIME` is in fact on the first line

Comment: Should make a PR to fix that :P

Answer (score 21):

## TrumpScript - Making PPCG Great Again ([TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript))

When trying to run this language on a windows PC, the output is always:

```
Make sure the currently-running OS is not Windows, because we're not PC
```

So when running this program:

```
Make sure the currently-running OS is not Windows, because we're not PC
```

It won't even parse it because the OS check fails, and you get the error message. Examples can be given for Mac as well if anyone wants them haha. God I've wanted to use this in PPCG for awhile now, good that I finally get to.

Full list of errors that can be triggered using environmental specifics:
https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript/blob/master/src/trumpscript/utils.py

---

## Bonus Answer: ArnoldC ([ArnoldC](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC))

ArnoldC requires root declaration of `IT'S SHOWTIME`, meaning `main()`, so:

```
WHAT THE FUCK DID I DO WRONG
```

Results in the only error message in ArnoldC...

```
WHAT THE FUCK DID I DO WRONG
```

Which, is actually... hilarious. You have to run it non-verbose though w/o stack traces.

Comment: These should be two separate answers.

Answer (score 15):

## Z-machine interpreter

```
I don't know the word "know".
```

Test against [this popular interpreter](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/1g84m0sXpnNCv84GpN2PLZG/the-game-30th-anniversary-edition).  Also there's some sort of mostly harmless game hosted there.

Comment: Interpreter no longer functions due to lack of Flash support. Link an HTML5 version?

Comment: Good callout - I've updated the link!

Comment: This quine made me laugh simply due to the hitchhikers guide reference :)

Answer (score 15):

## Mathematica

```
Syntax: "needed." is incomplete; more input is needed.
```

A `.` in *Mathematica* means either a decimal point or function `Dot`. In this case, the `.` appears at the end of an expression and cannot be interpreted.

---

[image]

Comment: I didn't think it was possible.

Answer (score 12):

### Julia 0.2.0

Another syntax error found iteratively until a fixed point was reached:

```
ERROR: syntax: extra token "token" after end of expression
```

Answer (score 11):

## AppleScript

```
A identifier can’t go after this identifier.
```

Both `A` and `identifier` can be identifiers, so AppleScript says no.

[image: identifiers]

Comment: it should be *an* identifier... come on....

Answer (score 10):

## C++ (g++)

The file must be saved as `1.pas`.

```
g++: error: 1.pas: Pascal compiler not installed on this system
```

Comment: Does it still work if the Pascal compiler *is* installed in the system?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 At least installing FreePascal doesn't help. I suppose GNU Pascal might be the right Pascal compiler, but I didn't try.

Answer (score 10):

## [INTERCALL](//github.com/theksp25/INTERCALL), 90 bytes

```
Fatal error: A INTERCALL program must start with the mandatory header to prevent golfing.\n
```

Includes a trailing newline at the end. Note that this isn't STDERR, but it was considered to be error output by many, so I posted it here.

This is the "mandatory header":

```
INTERCALL IS A ANTIGOLFING LANGUAGE
SO THIS HEADER IS HERE TO PREVENT GOLFING IN INTERCALL
THE PROGRAM STARTS HERE:
```

Comment: The link to the repo is broken.

Comment: @connectyourcharger Hm, looks like there's no repo anymore.

Comment: Yeah, Google searches yield nothing except for repos for Intercal.

Comment: @connectyourcharger No need to; there are only 8 repos called "intercall" (case-insensitive), and none of them are about the language, so it's safe to say it's gone for good (no, there's nothing in the Wayback Machine either).

Answer (score 10):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 9 bytes

```
RRRERROR!
```

[Link to interpreter](//soaku.github.io/Pepe/) (paste the code above, permalink removes the `!` and `O`)

**Explanation:**

The interpreter ignores characters other than `R`,`r`,`E`,`e` so the code is:

```
RRRERRR
```

Now to explain:

```
  RE    # Push 0
RR      # (RR flag: doesn't exist)
    RRR # There is no command RRR, so output RRRERROR!
```

Comment: I like the enthusiasm of this error message.

Answer (score 9):

## C

I applied the method of repeatedly copying the error messages to the source.  It converged in 2 cycles.  Compiled on OSX 10.9 with 'cc -c error.c'.

```
error.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'error'
error.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'error'
^
error.c:1:6: error: expected identifier or '('
error.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'error'
     ^
2 errors generated.
```

Note: This is not so much an answer as it is a methodology to get one.  The result might change depending on your OS or the version of cc you are using.

The exact method to get the result is to execute the instructions

```
$ cc -c error.c 2>out ; mv out error.c ; cat error.c
```

repeatedly until the output stops changing.

Comment: I retried.  It didn't work at first.  To make it work you have to execute `cc -c error.c 2>out` and then `mv out error.c`.  And with the version of cc I have today it takes a few more iterations.

Comment: You may want to note that in your answer, that it requires a specific version of OSX `cc`; otherwise it is invalid and must be deleted per community guidelines.

Comment: @MDXF: It works with clang. Here is a link to tio.run, 122 bytes: https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///Xy85PyVVryQzXy/ZyhAIFVKLivKLgFRFQWpySWqKQmZKal5JZlpmapFCfpGCuoY6Fxla4rgMIaoU0lPzUosSgar0/v8HAA

Comment: You get a nice long one with `gcc -v -Wall -pedantic` but it still converges quickly e.g. `error.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'Apple' Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)`

Answer (score 9):

## Applescript (in Script Editor)

```
Syntax Error
A "error" can't go after this identifier.
```

[image]

Comment: it's *an* error?

Comment: The article "A" appears before words which start with a consonant or a consonant sound. For words which begin with a vowel or a vowel sound, the correct article is "an". I'm just being nitpicky :)

Comment: @cat I see.  Yep, I never claimed grammatical correctness :)

Answer (score 8):

## GHCi (a Haskell interpreter/shell)

```
Code.hs:1:1: Parse error: naked expression at top level
```

#### Usage:

Write the code in a file named Code and load with GHCi.

A nice fact is that, if the words were actual identifiers, this would be a legal expression (as long as it would typecheck). This is basically due to the fact that `:` is a built in operator, `.` is used for module-qualified names, and whitespace is used to denote function application.

Comment: `.` isn't an operator here. It's part of a qualified name. What version of GHCi is this for?

Comment: @dfeuer yeah, my bad. Feel free to fix it. The ghci version is probably around whatever was out at the time.

Answer (score 8):

## BBC Basic, 7 bytes (or 0 Bytes)

This is a valid 7 byte entry:

```
Mistake
```

This is the error message produced by the interpreter when it is completely unable to make sense of the code.

On the other hand, this is not:

```
ERROR
```

This is a valid keyword in BBC Basic which is supposed to deliberately introduce an error of a specified code into the program, but the syntax is wrong (no code is given.) Therefore it returns `Syntax error` (which in turn returns `Mistake` when it is run.)

In general the procedure described by Falko in his answer leads to `Mistake` in BBC basic. There are a few exceptions. anything producing the errors`DATA not LOCAL` or `ON ERROR not LOCAL` leads to the famous zero byte quine: an empty source code produces an empty file.

Given that most error messages in BBC basic are lowercase (and therefore not valid keywords) I am pretty sure that any invalid input will ultimately lead to one of these possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

#### Ruby 2 on Windows

*Code:*

```
error.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
error.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tI...
          ^
```

The code was found by testing and iterating the process over and over until a fix-point was reached. The code must be inside the file `"error.rb"`.

*Demo:*

```
C:\>type error.rb
error.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTR
ING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
error.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tI...
          ^

C:\>ruby.exe error.rb
error.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTR
ING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
error.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tI...
          ^
```

Answer (score 7):

## C (gcc)

```
error.c:1:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 error.c:1:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
      ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Compile with `gcc -Wfatal-errors error.c`.

Answer (score 7):

## CJam 0.6.2

```
Syntax error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: y not handled
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 7):

## x86 assembly

Bytecode:

```
53 65 67 6d 65 6e 74 61 75 69 6f 6e 20 66 61 75
6c 74 20 28 63 6f 72 65 20 64 75 6d 70 65 64 29
```

i.e. the text

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Crashes immediately because the second instruction (the first being just "push %[er]bx") is

```
insl (%dx), %gs:(%di)
```

which fails because (a) ins cannot take segment overrides, (b) %dx and %di are almost certainly uninitialized, (c) %di is a 16-bit memory address and therefore can't be accessed in long mode, (d) ins is an invalid instruction outside of real mode.

The exact output may vary depending on what system this is run on, but it is likely that it will contain some form of illegal instruction.

Comment: To be precise, the text `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` is generated by your shell. If you [`set +m`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25) before running your program, you won’t see anything.

Answer (score 7):

## m4 (before 1.4.18-3 Termux patch), Termux, Android 11, 35 bytes

Who said the error had to be caused directly?

```
FORTIFY: %n not allowed on Android
```

Includes trailing newline.

m4 uses a very old version of Gnulib.

Since Android doesn't support `%n` in printf, Gnulib will replace every `printf` function in libc with its own custom implementation.

However, stupidly, said function will still use libc's `snprintf` function internally (which it is supposedly trying to replace because it doesn't work ), and when using it, [it attempts to use `%n` every single time it is called](https://github.com/tar-mirror/gnu-m4/blob/c8f51e6cbd0f5f75d9014222ce87caea626359ac/lib/vasnprintf.c#L4861), *even if `%n` isn't in the original format string.*

`%n` used to be silently ignored on Android (similar to macOS), [but Android 11 made these errors fatal](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/41398d03b7e8e0dfb951660ae713e682e9fc0336), causing this error to be printed followed by `abort()`.

I used `set +m` to prevent Bash from printing the signal error, and I had to compile from source to undo the -3 patch.

The file itself doesn't matter: m4 is guaranteed to crash no matter what. This includes running with no arguments.

[See this Github issue](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/4381)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## zsh (Linux)

`zsh: command not found: zsh:`

Should work with some small changes in just about any other shell.

Answer (score 5):

## CoffeeScript

Fails on first error, so it's fairly easy to do:

```
E:\foo.coffee:1:3: error: unexpected \
E:\foo.coffee:1:3: error: unexpected \
  ^
```

**Demo**

```
E:\>coffee -c foo.coffee
E:\foo.coffee:1:3: error: unexpected \
E:\foo.coffee:1:3: error: unexpected \
  ^

E:\>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Forth

[Try it here](http://repl.it/iJE)

This was surprisingly easy to come up with.

```
a : error(-13): word not found
```

Answer (score 5):

## Bash

```
$ bash: bash:: command not found
bash: bash:: command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

## ArnoldC, 28 bytes

```
WHAT THE FUCK DID I DO WRONG
```

This is the only error message in ArnoldC, though you do have to turn off stack traces.

Answer (score 5):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) 4.1

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'No', needed by 'make'.  Stop.
```

This is **syntactically valid**:

- Make tries to evaluate the target named `make` (first target is the default),
- which depends on the target named `No`,
- which it has no rule for.

Comment: But don't `***`, `'No'`, and `Stop.` contain syntactically invalid tokens? Also, have you noticed that your profile shows a picture of someone **r**ushing but your name is **e**ush77?

Comment: @MDXF Oh, no. `***` is a wildcard, `'No'` is quoted, and the dot in `Stop.` is allowed (as in filenames, e.g. `Stop.c`). You can run `make --debug` to see for yourself that it proceeds exactly as I described. You can also `touch No` to see the message change :)

Comment: @MDXF I'm sorry, I didn't get the joke about **r**ushing and the first letter of my name. Is it somehow unusual on this site?

Comment: Ah, okay. +1 and I didn't mean for it to be a joke; I thought you may have had a typo in your username. My bad.

Comment: @MDXF I never thought about my username this way! No, its origin is totally unrelated to the pic :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Malbolge](https://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge.shtml), 32 bytes

```
invalid character in source file
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/z8zrywxJzNFITkjsSgxuSS1SCEzT6E4v7QoOVUhLTMHqAIA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html), using [npiet](https://www.bertnase.de/npiet/) interpreter

```
cannot read from `Error.txt'; reason: unknown PPM format
```

Save as 'Error.txt' and put it in the same folder as the npiet executable. If you want to golf, you can of course choose a shorter filename and adjust the code to match.

Comment: Glad someone else thought of Piet. I really want to make my own image-based esolang some day.

Answer (score 4):

## Lua

Code:

```
lua: ERROR.lua:1: function arguments expected near '.'
```

It seems fairly easy to do with lua. I also modified it to work on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) as:

```
luac: prog.lua:1: function arguments expected near '.'
```

[Try it.](http://ideone.com/7K9BsJ)

Comment: Yeah, got it in few iterations starting from single `local`. Won't you mind if I'll explain this in answer's body?

Answer (score 4):

## Rebol

Interestingly, the error message here parses as symbols/tokens:

```
x
** Script error: x has no value
** Where: do either either either -apply-
** Near: do intern code
```

So despite looking error-like, it could be made a valid Rebol program if you gave all the words meanings.

However if you wanted an error at the parse phase vs. a runtime error in the code, the program/error could be:

```
1A
** Syntax error: invalid "integer" -- "1A"
** Where: to case load either either -apply-
** Near: (line 1) 1A
```

So given that distinction is possible, you can do fun things if you redefine `**` from exponentiation into something else (which I can't think of how to make useful for this particular challenge, given it's a quine.)

*(Note: Trying to abuse it for a trick uncovered a peculiarity of what happens when `**` (an infix operator) is redefined and then used immediately after.  I tried:*

```
**: function [:a :b :c :d :e :f] []
** Syntax error: invalid "integer" -- "1A"
** Where: to case load either either -apply-
** Near: (line 1) 1A
```

*My goal was to override the `**` so that it would accept its arguments unevaluated.  That way `** Syntax error: invalid "integer" -- "1A"` (or whatever) would not attempt to assign `invalid` to `error`, but pass the symbols to `**`.  But because `**` is infix it attempted to raise the function body to the power of `Syntax` prior to the completion of the assignment of `**:`.*

*It can be remedied by putting any token between the `[]` and the `**`.  But it helps to remember how your language evaluator works.  :-P)*

Answer (score 4):

### R (GUI)

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "Error: unexpected symbol"
```

The issue here is replicating the `"`, which causes the error message to change from `unexpected symbol` to `unexpected string constant`. Pretty much any error R throws will have the form `Error: <something> in "<bad code>"`, so you will pretty much *always* have to contend with the quoting. I tried this several other ways and always ended up falling back here.

Answer (score 4):

**Pyth**

```
    s_push: parser stack overflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyth.py", line 752, in <module>
    exec(code_to_remove_tools + py_code_line, environment)
MemoryError
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s_push%3A+parser+stack+overflow%0ATraceback+%28most+recent+call+last%29%3A%0A++File+%22pyth.py%22%2C+line+752%2C+in+%3Cmodule%3E%0A++++exec%28code_to_remove_tools+%2B+py_code_line%2C+environment%29%0AMemoryError&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (Chrome/V8), <s>65</s> <s>41</s> 39 Bytes

```
Uncaught =u=_=>{throw`=u=${u};u()`};u()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/PzQvObE0PaNEwbbUNt7Wrrokoyi/PAHIUakurbUu1dBMAJP//wMA)

Answer (score 4):

**Python 3, 28 bytes**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 46 bytes

```
I smell no triangularity. YOU SHALL NOT PASS!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/31OhODc1J0chL1@hBFlGTyHSP1Qh2MPRx0fBzz9EIcAxOFiR6/9/AA)

The language requires programs to be in the form of a triangle. If not, it denies you the gate to programming in the world of triangles. It will not let you pass.

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) v1.45.2 (via Rust Playground)

Code (1126 bytes):

```
error: unknown start of token: `
 --> src/lib.rs:1:32
  |
1 | error: unknown start of token: `
  |                                ^
  |
help: Unicode character '`' (Grave Accent) looks like ''' (Single Quote), but it is not
  |
1 | error: unknown start of token: '
  |                                ^

error: unknown start of token: `
 --> src/lib.rs:4:36
  |
4 | 1 | error: unknown start of token: `
  |                                    ^
  |
help: Unicode character '`' (Grave Accent) looks like ''' (Single Quote), but it is not
  |
4 | 1 | error: unknown start of token: '
  |                                    ^

error: character constant must be escaped: '
 --> src/lib.rs:7:56
  |
7 | help: Unicode character '`' (Grave Accent) looks like ''' (Single Quote), but it is not
  |                                                        ^

error: unterminated character literal
 --> src/lib.rs:9:36
  |
9 | 1 | error: unknown start of token: '
  |                                    ^

error: aborting due to 4 previous errors

error: could not compile `playground`.
```

[Try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bcdd9bc1e61541f93c38f5eb5647264e) (error message might differ in future versions of the language, though)

Compile errors in Rust all start with "error:", so copy/pasting the errors into the source a bunch of times eventually leads to these error messages. Default settings for the Rust Playground were used. That means 2018 edition, stable branch, and debug mode. I don't know what the target triple is.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 42 bytes

```
slice expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=slice%20expected%20at%20least%201%20arguments%2C%20got%200&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## Go

Another fairly easy one using the "general approach" provided in the other answer. I still like my JavaScript ones better.

```
can't load package: package : 
prog.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'IDENT' can
prog.go:2:2: invalid package name _
```

[Try it.](https://ideone.com/UwcWPU)

Answer (score 3):

### Lua (console), 35 bytes

This is what you get in the Lua console with the usual iterative approach:

```
stdin:1: '<name>' expected near '1'
```

which is a bit shorter than the one obtained for putting the code in a file.

Answer (score 3):

## ksh

```
$ ksh: ksh::  not found.
ksh: ksh::  not found.
```

Comment: Also works with bash: `bash: bash:: comand not found`

Comment: @shelvacu on my build of bash, `bash: command not found` errors with `bash:: command not found`, which errors with `bash::: command not found`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ConfusedMr_C must be a case of different versions. I am running 4.3.042-3 on x64 Arch Linux, and it works.

Comment: @shelvacu I'm running x64 Ubuntu, with whatever version of bash came with Ubuntu 14.04.3. Also, you can do `zsh: command not found: zsh:` in zsh.

Comment: @shelvacu Sorry, I just found out, I'm using `4.3.11(1)-release` on x64 Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Comment: @DarkAjax ksh version 93u+ returns `ksh: ksh::: not found.`

Comment: @VoteToSpam You are probably running bash in a repl. You can get the right message using `bash -c 'bash: bash:: ...'`.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl

```
syntax error at quine.pl line 2, at EOF
Execution of quine.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Replace `quine.pl` with whatever you named the file and enjoy.

Comment: Is it even possible to have a syntax error in perl? From what I've read online (mainly here) it seems as though perl accepts anything?

Answer (score 3):

## Java, in Eclipse

```
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

Answer (score 3):

## Factor

```
No word named "No" found in current vocabulary search path
```

Guess what it prints?

```
No word named "No" found in current vocabulary search path
```

Answer (score 3):

## Processing IDE

Probably the friendliest error message I've ever seen.

```
Syntax error, maybe a missing semicolon?
```

#### Result

[image: doodoood]

Technically this is cheating a bit because the pane below it prints `expected SEMI, found 'error'`. Unfortunately the word `error` is written in single quotes, so trying to copy that into the source of the program causes it to spit out a massive "Badly formed character constant" error... which does not include *any* singly-quoted words allowing for it to quine itself.

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC

```
NEXT without FOR in 0:1
```

Whenever the pre-run parser encounters a `NEXT` which isn't paired with a `FOR`, it produces the error `NEXT without FOR in slot:line`. Here, the code is in slot 0 and on line 1.

Comment: `Syntax error in 0:1` is shorter

Comment: I had that first, but this is a popularity-contest, so I went with something more creative.

Answer (score 3):

## [A Pear Tree](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree)

```
a partridge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/a-pear-tree#@5@oUJBYVFKUmZKeyvX/PwA)

Almost every program (that isn't very long) prints `a partridge` in A Pear Tree.

One of the goals of the language was to be good at [polyglot](/questions/tagged/polyglot) challenges; as such, it tries to find a substring of the program that has a very specific property that rarely occurs by chance, and starts running the program there. If it can't find an appropriate entry point, it prints an error. The actual text of the error message was chosen for the *The Twelve Days of Christmas* reference. (Actually, the design for the language worked the other way round; the main goal was to have a language which errored out on almost any source code, so that it would make the reference in question, so I set about trying to work out what sort of language design would naturally end up doing that.)

Answer (score 3):

## (t)csh

```
Unmatched '.
```

The trailing newline is needed to produce an *exact* match. Run it with `csh quine.csh` (or just type it into the shell, that works too).

Answer (score 3):

## Cubically, 94 bytes

```
Notepad: 0

   000
   000
   000
111222333444
111222333444
111222333444
   555
   555
   555
```

There are newlines at the start and end. (Cubically automatically dumps its memory to STDERR when the program finishes.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P@fyy@/JLUgMcVKwYCLS0FBwcDAAI0yNDQ0MjIyNjY2MTHBwwGqNjU1RaX@/wcA)

Comment: Technically this isn't an error. so it does not "generate at least one error message"

Comment: This seems to be an error message as far as I can tell.  It does output to STD*ERR* afterall.

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, <del>323</del> <del>166</del> 164 bytes

Call your program `a.` and use `rustc a.`.

```
error: unknown start of token: \
 --> a.:1:32
  |
1 | error: unknown start of token: \
  |                                ^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 71 bytes

code and error:

```
R is not a unary operator
Fatal error while parsing, execution aborted.
```

also:

```
Hit end of tokens while parsing expression
Fatal error while parsing, execution aborted.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRDYAwCAXAf6d4AxjHcAA3QCVK0gChNOr0eOfiVRukQy1BGErxwZyD0mJaKamBIyzw3NIYTtFFrxn88jFSTEG7RfK5VP0)

Answer (score 3):

### [Setanta](https://try-setanta.ie/), 97 bytes

```
Eisceacht ar líne 1: Suíomh 19: Ag súil le uimhir, téacs, bool, athróg, liosta, nó gníomh.
```

[Try it here!](https://try-setanta.ie/editor/EhEKBlNjcmlwdBCAgIDg6ZmECg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 20 bytes

```
You don't grok Grok.
```

[Try it Online!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=You%20don%27t%20grok%20Grok.&inputs=)

Grok has only one error message, and one of the ways to trigger it is to try to execute an invalid command. In this case, `oun'tgrG.` are all invalid commands, so when the execution reaches the first `o`, it errors out, printing the source code.

Answer (score 3):

## Desmos

`Sorry, I don't understand the '"' symbol.`

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q0w3njcgxe

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I seem to get a different error when I go to that link: `You need something on both sides of the '.' symbol.`

Comment: I couldn't make the code you posted work, but `Sorry, I don't understand the '"' symbol.` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I had tested it without the period. editing now.

Comment: Dupe answers are allowed per meta consensus, but keep in mind that this is essentially a dupe answer of this [post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36260/make-an-error-quine/253419#253419). You also need to include the byte count in the header of your post. In your case that would be 41 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
  File ".code.tio", line 1
        File ".code.tio", line 1
        ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X0HBLTMnVUFJLzk/JVWvJDNfSUchJzMvVcGQSwEKCCqI4/LMS0nNK0kEyua5FhXlF1kplOalVhSkJpekpihkgiX//wcA)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge on Wasabi v1.4

There is an interpreter for Befunge called Wasabi, and when an error appears the error message is in the format of a dialog box. This is the program:

```
Unsupported Command : 'U' at (1, 0). Ignore next syntax error(s)?
```

To test, download Wasabi v1.4 and insert the above program.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 66 bytes

```
Undefined function 'Undefined' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

This outputs the same to STDERR (shown in the console in red):

[image]

This is actually pretty unknown functionality (and it's rarely useful), which is why the [MATLAB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/95951#comment272694_95951) submission in the "Hello World!"-challenge may be improved.

This works because MATLAB will automatically interpret a command on the form `<word_1 word_2 word_3 word_4>`, with no surrounding brackets, as a function on the form:

```
word_1('word_2')`
```

That is, it calls a function `word_1` and gives the single input argument after the first, and in front of the second space as a string input to that function.

"Real life"-examples that can be used for golfing:

```
disp Hello   % Shorter than disp('Hello')
Hello

disp Hello World!
Hello

nnz variable
ans =
     8
```

Note that it will *always* interpret it as a string, it will not evaluate it:

```
variable = 3;
nnz variable
ans =
     8
nnz(variable)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: In my current MATLAB version (R2016b), this can be considerably shortened to 43 bytes: `Undefined function or variable 'Undefined'.`.

Comment: Really, it doesn't treat the words after `Undefined` as string inputs? What happens if you do `Undefined('function','or','variable')`? In previous versions these commands are equivalent. It doesn't tell you that the character input is invalid? It makes sense, but it's definitely new behavior. What about `a=2;b={};a(b)`. Or just `a({1})` without initializing anything first?

Comment: It does, hence "function or variable". However, I think the old error message was misleading, because 'Undefined' does not have to be a function, but could indeed be a variable, and many (most) functions are defined for arbitrary input, seeing as there is no native way that I know of to define a function like `y=f(uint32 x)`, so saying that a function is not defined for 'char' does not make sense.

Comment: As for your examples: `Undefined('function','or','variable')` returns `Undefined function or variable 'Undefined'.` (indeed, you could be indexing into the variable `Undefined`); the latter two examples give `Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.`

Comment: I agree, the new behavior makes more sense than the old one... I'm just surprised that they changed it. It makes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38240367/2338750) slightly outdated.

Comment: I don't have the new MATLAB version so I can't test it and create a screenshot myself. Feel free to add it as a separate answer if you like :)

Comment: Well, this is officially a popcon and it reduces a somewhat interesting error quine to the most basic one possible, so I won't post a new one. And yes, your Q&A should now include an 'up to' version number (although I don't feel like combing through the changelogs to see when they changed it).

Answer (score 2):

## NASM for x86: 45 bytes

`e.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected`

Assemble (or attempt to assemble) with `nasm e.asm`

Just in case:

```
0:beau@beau-Latitude-E6330:[~/asm/q]$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.12.02 compiled on Feb  5 2017
0:beau@beau-Latitude-E6330:[~/asm/q]$
```

Comment: −3 B: The file name can be `e.`

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Code](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), 70 bytes

```
Syntax error on line 1: <current symbol> should be a single character!
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?975820f09d73eed837a131c3e71213ae)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 39 bytes

```
Could not infer valid type for program
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zm/NCdFIS@/RCEzLy21SKEsMSczRaGksiBVIS2/SKGgKD@9KDGX6/9/AA) The infamous error that everyone is familiar with. Interestingly, I had trouble finding any other error quines: `Parse error (missing \): ¶` is nearly one in verbose mode, but it outputs `Parse error (missing \): ): ¶¶`.

Comment: Haha.. Use the error to generate the error.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift

This is a *bit* of a stretch. Bear with me.

The source MUST be encoded as UTF-16. Formatting the following as UTF-16:

```
swift.swift:1:1: error: input files must be encoded as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16
??^@s^@w^@i^@f^@t^@.^@s^@w^@i^@f^@t^@:^@1^@:^@1^@:^@ ^@e^@r^@r^@o^@r^@:^@^@i^@n^@p^@u^@t^@ ^@f^@i^@l^@e^@s^@ ^@m^@u^@s^@t^@ ^@b^@e^@\^@e^@n^@c^@o^@d^@e^@d^@ ^@a^@s^@ ^@U^@T^@F^@-^@8^@ ^@i^@n^@s^@t^@e^@a^@d^@ ^@o^@f^@ ^@U^@T^@F^@-^@1^@6^@
```

where `^@` is emacs-speak for an embedded `NUL` and the `?` characters are genuine ASCII question marks. Outputting to console (`cat` doesn't work, being ignorant of UTF16):

`$ iconv -f utf-16 swift.swift`

```
swift.swift:1:1: error: input files must be encoded as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16
??swift.swift:1:1: error: input files must be encoded as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16
```

and compiling:

`$ swiftc swift.swift`

We get:

```
swift.swift:1:1: error: input files must be encoded as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16
??swift.swift:1:1: error: input files must be encoded as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16
```

As desired.

CAVEATS:

- The terminal is taking the 16-bit header BOM `\xFF\xFE` in the error message from `swiftc` and degrading it as ASCII `??` in the console.
- When the swift compiler is run *in an Emacs shell*, the terminal settings *do not* process the unprintable ASCII characters, instead rendering them in Octal.
- When the source is rendered *in an Emacs buffer*, which is UTF-16 aware, the first line appears correctly, and the ?? appears correctly, and but the remaining characters are shown interspersed with `NUL` literals rendered as `^@`.
- `cat` in the Terminal doesn't work either, being unaware of UTF-16.
- A UTF16-aware output utility is needed: `iconv -f utf-16 swift.swift`, where the terminal emulator subsequently discards the interspersed `NUL` characters on the second line.
- In MacOS, `swiftc` leverages terminal capabilities to produce bold and color escape codes. To avoid this ambiguity, you can use `export TERM=dumb`.

I'm claiming it's a quine as long as the source is rendered with a UTF-16 aware output utility and a terminal that discards ANSI formatting, NULs, and degrades unprintable characters to `?`.

*USING TextEdit*

You can also make a more visually convincing argument using `˛ˇ` in place of `??` where you keep the input as UTF-16 and let Swift output the (invalid) UTF-8 output with `swiftc swift.swift > out 2>&1` and open `out` in TextEdit. Side by side, the input and output indeed are rendered identically. No less dubious under the covers, but looks *a lot* less dubious.

So...when you say *exactly identical*, what *exactly* do you mean?

If the output must be re-usable as the input, the quine constraint is indeed violated. And if you argue it's OK to cycle the UTF8 compiler output *back* to UTF16 source, that seems promising, but doesn't work because the output of `swiftc` is neither valid UTF-8 *nor* UTF-16: it is not valid to embed the BOM header midstream in either encoding. It's just terminal poo. Having fun yet?

It's an interesting foray into encoding and terminals, at the least!

Answer (score 2):

## [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda), 95 bytes

After a few attempts, I finally found a solution in my favorite dependently typed language! Agda includes the full filename in place of `error.agda` on lines 1 & 2.

```
error.agda:3,1-1
error.agda:3,1: Parse error
)<ERROR>
<ERROR>
<ERROR>
<ERROR>
<ERROR...
```

Save file as `error.agda` and prepend the full filepath on those first two lines for a local answer, or here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xPSfz/X78kt0A/OT8lVS8RyLcy1jHUNeTCFLRSCEgsKk5VSC0qyi/iqrVxDQryD7Ljwk/r6en9/w8A)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 24 bytes

```
ERR:SYNTAX
1:Quit
2:Goto
```

lowercase characters outside strings are a syntax error

[image: screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 41 bytes

```
Sorry, I don't understand the '?' symbol.
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e7bskujusg)

Hover over the danger sign to view the error message.

There could be something shorter but I don't have time to go through every single error out there in Desmos lol.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator)

```
Sorry, I don't understand the '&' symbol.
```

Go to [desmos.com/calculator](https://desmos.com/calculator) and paste in the "code".

Answer (score 2):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/)

```
error: parse error: likely incomplete statement
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0msyPz/P7WoKL/ISqEgsag4VQHKycnMTs2pVMjMS87PLchJLUlVKC5JLEnNTc0r@f8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra

```
test.cobra(1): error: Expecting use, assembly, namespace, class, interface or enum, but got "test".
Compilation failed - 1 error, 0 warnings
Not running due to errors above.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++

(Using Apple LLVM in Xcode)

```
Unknown type name 'Unknown'
Expected ';' after top level declarator
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Loader](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Loader) (using the official Java interpreter):

These should be run from a module named `main` in order to produce the exact error messages given here.

**This works in the most recent version of the interpreter:**

```
Error: Could not evaluate expression Error (module main, line 1)
```

Explanation:

`expression:statement` is a conditional. The interpreter doesn't even syntax check the stuff to the right of the colon (if it did, we'd get a different error message) unless the stuff on the left evaluates to a nonzero value. However, as "Error" is an illegal expression, the interpreter can't evaluate it, exiting the program with this error message.

**In some earlier interpreter versions, this would work instead:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not evaluate expression Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException (module main,line 1)
    at Loader.expr(Loader.java:183)
    at Loader.load(Loader.java:201)
    at Loader.main(Loader.java:249)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/)

Here's my contribution:

```
[chuck]:line(1).char(8): syntax error
```

This works if you first type it into the editor, save it as "chuck", and then run it once. If you run it another time the number in `char()` goes up by eight.

ChucK can be downloaded [here.](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/release/)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://cjam.aditsu.net)

```
Syntax error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: y not handled
```

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37367

Answer (score 1):

### [Straw](http://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw)

```
/opt/straw/straw.rb:108:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /opt/straw/straw.rb:108:in `new'
    from /opt/straw/straw.rb:108:in `step'
    from /opt/straw/straw.rb:225:in `run'
    from /opt/straw/straw.rb:254:in `<main>'
```

[Try It Online!](http://straw.tryitonline.net/#code=L29wdC9zdHJhdy9zdHJhdy5yYjoxMDg6aW4gYGluaXRpYWxpemUnOiBubyBpbXBsaWNpdCBjb252ZXJzaW9uIG9mIG5pbCBpbnRvIFN0cmluZyAoVHlwZUVycm9yKQoJZnJvbSAvb3B0L3N0cmF3L3N0cmF3LnJiOjEwODppbiBgbmV3JwoJZnJvbSAvb3B0L3N0cmF3L3N0cmF3LnJiOjEwODppbiBgc3RlcCcKCWZyb20gL29wdC9zdHJhdy9zdHJhdy5yYjoyMjU6aW4gYHJ1bicKCWZyb20gL29wdC9zdHJhdy9zdHJhdy5yYjoyNTQ6aW4gYDxtYWluPic&input=&debug=on)

Comment: Works only if path to interpreter is `/opt/straw/straw.rb`. (Not that this answer is bad, just to let you know.)

Comment: Oh, and also, Try it online! also outputs the timings for the program run and the exit code.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Throws a generic `Unexpected identifier` error (in Chrome, at least) because it doesn't recognize `Uncaught` as an identifier.

Comment: I presume that the exact text this generates is not in the standard. Could you please include the browser / JavaScript engine that this submission is "programmed" in?

Comment: It generates "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

## Codelike, 36 Bytes

```
Error at (1,1): Unknown character: E
```

[Try it!](https://github.com/dospunk/codelike)

Answer (score 1):

## Ada

```
test.adb:1:01: compilation unit expected
```

Really just make an ada file, toss it at the start as above and compile with `gcc filename.adb -c`.

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang

Works in the latest version of the reference implementation as of the time this answer was written.

```
Exception in thread "main" lang.exceptions.IllegalInvocationException: Exception is not a function.
    at lang.ForceLang.parse(ForceLang.java:52)
    at lang.ForceLang.main(ForceLang.java:129)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5

Note: the source file should be named "1" for this to work

```
  File "1", line 1
    File "1", line 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Answer (score 1):

### [GW-BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC) (least: 12 bytes)

```
Syntax error
```

Inspired by the [Commodore 64 BASIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36270/61563) answer. Knocked off 2 bytes because IBM and DOS are better than Commodore :P You can download an [emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pcbasic/) for GW-BASIC.

```
NEXT without FOR
```

Since GW-BASIC is a line-based language, it only evaluates the first instruction after a newline or colon `:`. Therefore, it reads `NEXT` and automatically fails it didn't read a `FOR`.

### [Apple ][ BASIC](https://www.scullinsteel.com/apple2/#logo) (13 bytes)

```
?SYNTAX ERROR
```

Woo, 1 less byte than the Commodore answer because the old Apples could beat a Commodore anyday :P

### [QBasic](https://repl.it/languages/qbasic) (43 bytes)

```
Parse failed: Syntax error at 1:1: Token(:)
```

Might be cheating because it only works on the first line.

### [Applesoft BASIC](http://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/) (69 bytes)

```
ParseError: Syntax error: Expected line number or separator in line 0
```

Also only works on the first line...

Answer (score 1):

## sed

By using this [general approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36262/42775), I have converged on several sed error quines. This may not work in your sed, in which case, you're using the wrong sed, and therefore would you please acquire necessary, error-quining sed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/ODXFSiEtMydVQS85PyVVryQzXyEnMy9VwdBKoTQvOy@/PE8hvwAomqdQkq@QUKz@/z8A) This version works in TIO, and probably not anywhere else. Open the "Debug" panel to see the error.

[image: <code>sed: 1: test.sed: bad flag in substitute command: 'd'</code> and <code>gsed: file toast.sed line 1: extra characters after command</code>]

Where `sed` is macOS's default `sed`, and `gsed` is a GNU `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 7 bytes

```
Error!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P/ftagov0iR6/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ly

```
Error occurred at program index 3, instruction o (zero-indexed, includes comments)
EmptyStackError: cannot pop from an empty stack
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMwDATvfcUeW0ih597zgrzAyGoJjSQjy9D0826c28AMs@29z@7mMKLmzhkpUNzengSrZv7iMR1QwxvFagrD9cdu91NyHpK2lrmCTIQ16u0yS4l9iUSfc/4EJVU7xlbwchMkBY8GdUS9/wE) (using official compiler)

This program makes use of the `o` in "Error", the first instruction character in the error message that produces an error. (apparently `r` does nothing with an empty stack)

When a stack is not empty, `o` takes the top entry off the selected stack and outputs it as ASCII;
`EmptyStackError` occurs when the selected stack is empty. So when Ly runs into this `o`, it causes this error, since we haven't given the stack anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

## VB.Net, 32 Bytes

Create a new, empty project named 'A'. Set the startup object to "Sub Main" (it's a drop-down option). Create a new class called anything. Delete everything from the class and copy/paste the following:

```
'Sub Main' was not found in 'A'.
```

This works because a single quote is a comment, so it looks like a blank file :D

Comment: [aw, couldn't get exact output on TIO](https://tio.run/##VY4xiwIxFIT7/IqpTHObgOUhwl5nIQqKfTYbvej6XtyX9Qrxt@9FPA62G5j5hq9x8j16l7FEjcVCB2r1qHdDg7WLpPHjBMQZRx6oRSToWpuxrFRHqI6SYWA5Zeul8uLtY9tzCn2OQT6S8xd3CmL/kzkL01P5NGH2q011@DL3JvV8hnk/F506pS4Wt8hUSiWhhbzGtraYMkX@L6r@Ou3UVZohdi0scccnhr1/3rCczcdf)

Answer (score 1):

## [ESOPUNK](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ESOPUNK), 38 bytes

```
Invalid instruction INVALID at line 0.
```

Comment: Wasn't this posted after the postdated language consensus was changed?

Comment: No idea, to be honest. I'm not exactly in the race for anything, though, so I'm not particularly worried.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 2 bytes

```
'c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/189@f9/AA)

'c is the response from the console indicating that the variable c is undefined

Comment: Apologies, I've edited, thought what I was getting was STDERR as I was operating in the console and saw the output replicated by oK in TiO

Answer (score 1):

## [MiLambda](https://github.com/TryItOnline/MiLambda)

```
ERROR_NOHALT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83MScxNSkn8/981KMg/KN7P38PRJ@T/fwA)

Seems like a short solution

Answer (score 1):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), 258 bytes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/tmbww/TuringMachineButWayWorse.py", line 16, in <module>
    i[0], i[2], i[3], i[5], i[6] =  int(i[0]), int(i[2]), int(i[3]), int(i[5]), int(i[6])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Traceback'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY@9bsJAEIR7nmJEA5asmB/hwiIUkZIuHQoFcrE@FjixvkPnNRZP7xxWFDejT7Ozq1mtq67r@30gwxWZG@a1bxSBDTuFIREINZoUE@DLCmOa@btm@lrL9m2w7vJN5modf7R6oOfBh4bf7s9pCokmlnkK67Ct/akV3sUrgD0uyugeV4OuB90Mmpd4j3On81cmSf9wNeJ6xM2IeZlMfkha/gzBhyK6DxJ7ihWUAwnOPgzJBJ3VKypqYrNFgdn/37O@/wU)

Comment: The rule about languages postdating the challenge has been abolished, you can compete all you want.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oh, okay

Answer (score 1):

## ZSH (macOS), 20 bytes excluding newline

```
 zsh: bad pattern: ^[
```

Comment: all error messages should include this: `: ^[`

Answer (score 1):

## [W.Y.A.L.H.E.I.N.](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/whenyouaccidentallylose100endorsementsinnationstates), 253 bytes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/wyalhein/whenyouaccidentallylose100endorsementsinnationstates.py", line 6, in <module>
    seed = int(contents[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY@xTsNAEET7fMUoTWIpwk5DYQEdfAGiSSg2d4t8Yr0b3a2x/PXmEtHTzsyb0cwLycBJ1/U9U@ALhW/sRyuOzIHVEUgEQsWbfgO8JWFsW7t6O/@R7TywLjZRCClWouYXscLHrmONlguPVS1JlTyZFifn8nBdtgdIUsbjAUnxNFqchF/qBlCYI56r7Ptg6jf81H02mw@SiV9zttxX84ckxdrhnEnwZfkONJiTD7hQYRy7Hrv/f511t66/)

whenyouaccidentallyloseahundredendorsementsinnationstates expects a seed on the first line, and `Traceback (most recent call last):` is not a valid number (unless we're talking in base 96, of course, but whenyouaccidentallyloseahundredendorsementsinnationstates doesn't).

Comment: You kinda get screwed by the length of the language name huh?

Comment: @JoKing Yeah. It was even shortened on TIO because the name was too long

Answer (score 1):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 42 bytes

```c
.code.tio.c:1: error: declaration expected
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/18vOT8lVa8kM18v2crQSiG1qCi/yEohJTU5J7EoESicp5BaUZCaXJKa8v8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## MS SQL (Server version 2012), 64 bytes

```
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '16'.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](https://julialang.org/) (Tio)

Implementation specific, but this  one is made to run in [Tio](https://tio.run).

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: syntax: extra token "token" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [3] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [4] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:229
 [5] _start() at ./client.jl:421
in expression starting at /home/runner/.code.tio:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBS8MwFIDv@xWPnSZIa9qJmqOwi0wGHXoZpcTkVbNlLyNJpfv19a0bQxBP4YXve/nItnNWiX4YFlW1qiQsvTKLEHyQ8EYG23cVLmM8UlK9BOxTUJD8Dgmm4zEF1SYMgGTAtwwcAsZoPU3WSekd4xrlBDaiBkvadQZBJcjyD@9TtnWyFA@wseQsoamZK65cE9CpZL9xJuWrN53DW5BynYKlz5vzEsfBPJ32iLvykfXyqv9vxWO0@1EqnliZ11yNuvGHxNmRvWcVMXtZrs4XF0s7izQmF6N2X0MTkwpp9geYF2Ji6ddfwAhywYnMv/we89ARYcgz7Q1m/I4Uw/AD)

Answer (score 1):

## Brain-flak

`Error at character 33: Unclosed '(' character.`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/37WoKL9IIbFEITkjsSgxuSS1SMHY2EohNC85J784NUVBXUMdIaX3/z8A)

## Haskell

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( .code.tio.hs, .code.tio.o )

.code.tio.hs:1:4: error: parse error on input ‘of’
  |
1 | [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( .code.tio.hs, .code.tio.o )
  |    ^^
/srv/wrappers/haskell: line 5: ./.bin.tio: No such file or directory
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pU@9CsIwGNzzFDcqSEpAl6zO@gJiIbapDdZ84UurCB36GPp6fZHY4tLd24774a428WabJqWTAlVQZ@zpHlzj/BUH4zyWWEEWVFrZOpJ13CwYYS3EUtRKbzUsM7FGMBztj4A8nA9di3F4UzUOHwH0QqHH/wumptmU5yKL/MiebEKwHLP6d1JjKrXYachMXpyfcxpHQuyKGpVrLKaBpWNbtMQvkdIX)

## Stack Cats

`Error: invalid character in source code, E | E ,edoc ecruos ni retcarahc dilavni :rorrE`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYy5CcAwEARb2QJcgXMVcqwOLGx8sHoi9y5fMMnATB/Gmzb63kUKnWjvsqdV8DIZhysNekzRwah@oOBLDq9BODWj422QD2ZxEbU9ttKc@VPZ@wc)

## Taxi

`error: parse error: likely incomplete statement`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0msyPz/P7WoKL/ISqEgsag4VQHKycnMTs2pVMjMS87PLchJLUlVKC5JLEnNTc0r@f8fAA)

## Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly language

```
/opt/hspal/hspal.rb:69:in `run': Illegal opcode: 170  (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/hspal/hspal.rb:75:in `<main>'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyguSMz5/18/v6BEPwPEhpB6RUlWZpZWmXkKCUWleepWCp45OanpiTkK@QXJ@SmpVgqG5gYKChpBpXklmbmprkVF@UWaXJxpRfm5CtiMMjcFG2WTm5iZZ6f@/z8A)

## Quarterstaff

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/quarterstaff/quarterstaff.py", line 142, in <module>
    QuarterstaffInterpreter(open(parser.parse_args().program).read())
  File "/opt/quarterstaff/quarterstaff.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.run(self.parse(program), {}, 0)
  File "/opt/quarterstaff/quarterstaff.py", line 35, in parse
    raise Exception
Exception
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY5BiwIxDIXv/oowpxaGqqsiLMveVvAoeC@xZqTYaWvagV3E3z47FJTxqJfkPUje9y4dciZOGZum7/eMhg5oziDakDIwGfIZDDoHDlOWnxOAjXUE1TTEPL2Mvp@Min9VDc56gvnyowbr4asNx87R95AAsBvdbv2gItMwRYjkRUROxKosjXxKQqrI4cTYSsWERyHl6z3WpYXW1tusdWmRyDWKOy@KKDxxB9VwvdUwewO0WBVSiSsYRpsIfn4NxWyDnzxU3/8D)

## Haxe

```
Main.hx:1: characters 0-4 : Unexpected Main
Uncaught exception - load.c(181) : Module not found : .bin.tio
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xCsMwDEX3nuKPzRBTQ4fiO2TMAVRZjQNBCqkNvr2rro/3eIW6jLHQrqH0FBO40EVc5friMT@RsKr0U5xk/LXbqkxtKxXSWc66m2LGYZQD3@MrTp4sltshUKv4WNPsKLz94PIYPw)

## Hasm

```
Error with instruction <internal{PARSE}> on line 0:
    Syntax error or illegal instruction: Error with instruction <internal{PARSE}> on line 0:
Dumping core:


STACK:
    
OFFSTACK:
    
HEAP:
    0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszv3/37WoKL9IoTyzJEMhM6@4pKg0uSQzP0/BJjOvJLUoLzGnOsAxKNi11k4BKJiTmZeqYGDFxRlcmVeSWKGQCtYLRJk5OanpiTnIJlgpkGOyS2luQWZeukJyflGqFRcXV3CIo7M30EIufzc3ONvD1TEASBso/P8PAA)

## Mornington Crescent

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mornington-crescent/esoterpret.py", line 123, in <module>
    arguments.stdin, extra)
  File "/opt/mornington-crescent/esoterpret.py", line 41, in use_language
    while not(interpreter.has_execution_finished()):
  File "/opt/mornington-crescent/modules/morningtoncrescent/morningtoncrescent.py", line 50, in has_execution_finished
    raise RuntimeError("You have to end at Mornington Crescent.")
RuntimeError: You have to end at Mornington Crescent.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY@7TsRADEX7/QorVSKFhOXRrNA2K@hoEA1VNExMMmLGjjweWL4@ZMNDEVCsaH117rkOLOSoU6YTKxgtko7jvRiLj8Y@Qx44Kgge7mCN9@BN1GKzArhxHiGredA6/C6pMbKiDIJaDW9ZCd4RwvrsvARHcBW4TR63Uw2AkS6FCYlV1NZRCbhXMcU/FRfr2ZAiNt5Ql0yHs@W1P5QRa@7ok0KpehMb3KNN6piaJ0cu9tjmxTEffvwQF9ki@nlaLLw8nRf@rZ63inER4S6RuoDXIix59sBpQl4QlAGpBaNw@22B3ZcmK1ZLbgNHcuP4Dg)

## Muriel

`*** ERROR: muriel: Unknown token '*'`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy0tykzN@f9fS0tLwTUoyD/ISiEXLGSlEJqXnZdfnqdQkp@dmqegrqX@/z8A)

Just picked some random esolangs from TIO and keyboard hashed until I got an error, then copy + pasted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), 21 bytes

```
Unknown mode for '$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P8/NC87L788TyE3PyVVIS2/SEFdRZ3r/38A)

Phooey ignores `Unknown mode for '`, then tries to parse `$'` which is an unknown mode for `$`.

Comment: Is the newline needed?

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), 1292 bytes (UTF-8)

```
DEBUG:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "x" is null
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.ops(Numbers.java:1068)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.incP(Numbers.java:141)
    at fig.compression$fromBijectiveBase$fn__191.invoke(compression.clj:26)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8181.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:168)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8181.invoke(protocols.clj:124)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8136$G__8131__8145.invoke(protocols.clj:19)
    at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:31)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8168.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:75)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8168.invoke(protocols.clj:75)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8110$G__8105__8123.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6830)
    at fig.compression$fromBijectiveBase.invokeStatic(compression.clj:26)
    at fig.compression$decompress.invokeStatic(compression.clj:39)
    at fig.compression$decompress.invoke(compression.clj:35)
    at fig.compression$decompress.invokeStatic(compression.clj:36)
    at fig.parsing$lex.invokeStatic(parsing.clj:40)
    at fig.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:38)
    at fig.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:19)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at fig.core.main(Unknown Source)
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#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)

The tabs sadly disable Fig's scoring system, so this is counted in UTF-8/ASCII. <s>Still no normal Fig quine...</s>

Comment: [not anymore](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253414/92689) :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2 + `EVAL`) (knight-lang.netlify.app implementation), 32 bytes

```
Error: Unknown identifier 'rror'
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyJFcnJvcjogVW5rbm93biBpZGVudGlmaWVyICdycm9yJyIsIiIsIjIuMCJd)

Different implementations handle errors differently (it is undefined behavior in the official specs), which is why I specified the implementation that I'm using.

Also, this technically only works in version 1.x because `EVAL` is removed as a required function in the v2 official specs, but this implementation has `EVAL` even though it is a v2 implementation, which is why I specified `EVAL` in the header just to be safe.

If `EVAL` wasn't implemented in this implementation, I think something like `Error: No value could be parsed!` would be a valid error quine instead (and it coincidentally turns out to also be 32 bytes).

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/blob/master/golf/expanded.c) (v1.2) (C (gcc) implementation), 21 bytes

```
invalid character 'i'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVhtU9tGEP5s/4rDGSydLDe2Qmc6NrKHpJBhSiCFpP0AbiJkGW4qy6ok56UJ@emlu3t30skW6SszWL693b1nX2535bB/E4b3j0QSxut5tJ8Xc7H65nbSNimxuK6RwuJjGtUoy6C43ZDKRHJTIxViKYXm0UIkEYtjFq@SG/pol9RXp69fsGG1vHh1zrxq@dPBOdurlkenz9h31fL8NRtWzEcnFwbv6esTg/X16YuDix/snDMbP7rsy/BbXu4eXMCxcjO8DTLm8ErA5AKspYrJhO1Ve6eHP@NmAptk0WeG3/f3N3jwGOJBM4Enjjky1nienp2dEBN@TMnIEdpmADl/LhlA3sD6LojXEeeXyYy322QHROVy5p93Ds@O7HuRAIOYM9wJwiLKmCWsew57nbFkd4A/CpbMR8Fxuw3a0yDLI5uzT@2WSAomxu0WUOkklzmLdRIChYRDWBfL1M3T5NKb@Z8G7uAOdLQEqCN@eA6Q8Pgxqhcpe38riihPgzBqt@B7HNlAB3FbwnBZ56q4Sq4WVxn7dHc5s/noUYcTlJZYMLtE6zPrkcWZVKGpO0C9SoDc60kK4GxFcR6ZhDsJJ7yNwl/ZYpWxZL28jrJc4WG2yOfiRhRaK5yO5gzd0iL5dNhwwHrMUch7Pc76zBpYcAQiFZxlUbHOEqZzQ4pReow3MbwLMhFcx5FGASDi1fsos0M4TwNhnz8zDS6kVUiOeGNx5R7RYLrwhy7EyC/JG@jwtqmsBJZkvk5tDClTPu0zWG0Dlnc/l9okjCvLqjB1LBk0EAYLSlAMlECtgO@ALA3yghW3ESgLsgKYVQAc7VEMaMjREg3WuEIPgoXPIadAtypnEHxM3UKsEoCNGTuYAbRQeyRfpyk6nOus0hTT/Wb@gdsNZ6MOncppAnkMdQszVyGXXnlllZdbEo6QgDVshLULYeoko7InTbURN0IN4ngV2nsDd8jRQCSXRpCByTqOg@yjaWgVn3MjPC@tEhkdqOTXyYY0HTHEI1RRaLL08Omztz/unHx/dvDFsNjUey0aFXvbindqmp8fXzygEUoZqQySOfttHeglqn1nHvFk@wjpgedW6YzjBmeQ8F5duM5zR7UyWycYorEqvk6xym1dLOkGQG4XIqQCzK7Xi0tvb6ZwyEh3qT6UAPIU7lWxsIEV7N@N43lHFx5qPi4q2VQAt6JUINuaPL/Gt8@GT@p2ovGYjFPWKbJ11IEkLOmYk0BfBFBCcKODqdWpnIB2ou2q/5A73jxdrWLYua574EFbK7O@ZpDzzy0yYV5vwYwRY/K/YoSkLVZxbJtQXTZwoUX8C8jJFmRswy8OXp662IxlosHy@HI4GAwgncAUWOpVLn6P3hQMH2MjRw1r0QOwcvHD070cSxu2c3zQJ@4cHZ8cOmwB5XDcKnNZHYCFNwxSN44S6vmGc/Q8JJ0EF@0h6zcFsRthM8MWYwuaHqD77pPxY2gjAjfLQhEu0w2Xk1fErKoZ6Bcxw2Py96IIb20HXLE1PqFTQmxJUCRHWlSNdxmUGJt3Bx8W@IfhlJwvgRMwSIw3URHDlGZ3yYld9BA2pblI@NjQRxNnkWHbggentiq1HUptchLDy4XzHpZ5LY1BVKWowvC0Qiv5y51n1Q5K4r/SWPG8BR70NUTXT1dplNjGwW4n61DrBVT@UnYeiLbvDfa@I7pq1rbs8AuAPkejYCSChHBxXgJ26MW0wjPgaB08G4is59NogRcAOLlyJuihs8iRqMHxmWfOAJUbK0t@BEuiDzAW4eXZsnOnFlMatXewMGwxnmwFH06J634x2L@3Rmruknnkm14uC4kq6J1TGjNtLOlc1/TJZI9Xg9pWddGiFzRs2bs5CpoJ3yQM7oRRwjwXChPvVKx6A6t1FCRK7UMdQbUAMwLq5iovnFVewLSXLxLoNBnPmutYt0vvJ/0@ss7k2HhF42tLw9r9xskBjw0rzvRFygz46yLX0S9zAmcnheegxENFCIoRljnMLCM6dGJVvH01WnkwWblYCH353oeS3K1nXKueIao9EWeVGl8IRJ2zX09Ozdr7W3hpmN5QaGCEW6e1ezJFcfxtSUtKfEjGyu7roHi8@WaFQaEfyjPDXhVVrr@jLo4uo2ehSpqyq791mQz7cVKv45VCTpVMDV7YbM4NfnC2/CDTsMkLywbTHOLxTSUkAA3Jpq7oW1fwjodM436f9ClHUePczhE6tlasHn/VMY@bHbP7VaHdZqFftoToVqWr96a0yzas1eL7G0lMlRPTsJapfj1Pp8wMx76pG0VH6neQLpMMU1br4/LCMSM/UcdASuqa7clCgrw7PpQrA/IELMa3g9V8NWLLaBmm@IKZsMnb6X81ZfI/mDLRpuw02OIrW5Qp04e9L09tgIzbU1Zj8EoOT1fgnSac1aI0T97A6grWcqtb5Rba0nRbp6Ykk/pK@c9/R56oI1NNKT@2RiZ3bU7a5PXJlTV3eeW1/kdzZnllykET@Vq1YdNXdraIBzXO/Jq0USBQAjl6vVJMQv4ZzJM/Q5iTSs061tD8jutjH7Ia8lNv9MRwy3M5c/pGi@4ZOd4wuCZqcq1KxpPaRHQhHb2hdKydbypXNM83NOnK7JXSe0T8ixaFwPCJoQjL6bFsUGa38sBCPLU3xLZFJVvmv9ykB3H01E2A0@fRIljHBVimR5SGX1V3QwuHFqRw9sBLBiqjKVX9PKVe7JaBSLAusyC7CV1S6jjw/R3Hnw/o9QN/VrcHhKb@HnB3/0e4iIOb/L4fL/8E)

Different implementation, different error messages :)

Answer (score 1):

## [gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.40](https://www.gnupg.org/), 157 bytes

Note `error` is followed by a newline.

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
```

### Usage in shell

I don't know if that source is REALLY a program source.

```bash
cat <<'X' >source
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
X
gpg <source >stdout 2>stderr
cat stdout
diff source stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ACCUMULATOR](https://undonestudios.github.io/accumulator.html), 7 bytes

```
Invalid
```

`Invalid` is the only error in ACCUMULATOR. This is because `I` is not a function in ACCUMULATOR.

Answer (score 1):

## [xidoc](https://xidoc.nim.town/), 66 bytes

```
Error while rendering file 
at 2:17-2:18 in []
Command not found:
```

## [xidoc](https://xidoc.nim.town/), 135 bytes

```
Error while rendering file 
at 3:26-3:26
Parse error: Unexpected ']'
3 │ Parse error: Unexpected ']'
  │                          ^
```

[Try it (you need to paste in the code)](https://xidoc.nim.town/playground.html)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 (IDLE)

```python
SyntaxError: incomplete input
```

This surprisingly outputs just itself and nothing else.

Comment: What Python version are you using? Python 1, 2, and 3 all throw a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` here for me

Comment: It outputted this in the IDLE shell… try in python 3.8 prerelease or python 3.11 @emirps

Comment: the IDLE has different output than the python interpreter, but this answer can be an answer in “Python IDLE” if that is what it outputs

Comment: Can confirm I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on 3.8 (pre-release) as well on TIO https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7gyrySxwrWoKL/ISiEzLzk/tyAntSQVyCwoLfn/HwA

Comment: It seems to work in IDLE, even on 3.11 though, so if you change your language to "Python 3 (IDLE)" this would be valid.

Comment: @mousetail done

Answer (score 1):

## [MirBSD pax](https://www.mirbsd.org/pax.htm), 127 bytes.

Includes trailing newline:

```
pax: End of archive volume 1 reached
pax: Cannot identify format. Searching...
pax: Sorry, unable to determine archive format.
```

### Usage

```
$ pax -f quine 
pax: End of archive volume 1 reached
pax: Cannot identify format. Searching...
pax: Sorry, unable to determine archive format.
$ pax < quine 
pax: End of archive volume 1 reached
pax: Cannot identify format. Searching...
pax: Sorry, unable to determine archive format.
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## [(,)](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/in-parens-comma/) 38 Bytes

```
code must be surrounded by parentheses
```

Litterally the only possible one on my current interpreter

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 12 bytes

```
u not handled
```

When operator doesn't exist, interpreter prints `* not handled`

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37367

Answer (score 0):

## Elixir

```
== Compilation error on file e.ex ==
** (SyntaxError) e.ex:3: keyword argument must be followed by space after: ex:
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:114: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Put the code in `e.ex` and compile with `elixirc e.ex`. There are also some blank lines in the output (and in the file), but I can't get them to appear on here; S.O. eats them.

Answer (score 0):

## F#

```
e.fs(1,11): error FS0010: Unexpected symbol ':' in implementation file
```

Compile with `fsc --nologo e.fs`. Again, there's an extra blank line I can't properly reproduce here. (Without the `--nologo` flag the compiler wants to announce itself and its version number and display a Microsoft copyright message.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Syms](https://github.com/CatsAreFluffy/syms), 202 bytes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/syms/syms.py", line 196, in <module>
    stack.append(("{"+str(stack.pop())+"}").replace("\\","\\\\").replace("&","\\&"))
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY49C8JAEET7/Ipli3CHIcFGMIidgr1lmjNZIXhf7J1gEH/7ucTGZgYevGHS4lIpVzYj3cz4AOVCysA0ks8wGmvBmpR1XwGcZ0uAXYi5S2Kt0cYFG7CzJ9judw3MHg4uTE9LRzEAUpbR1sRIflIK37hJmdWPxhCV1hv8oG6ZopULCocBGwmpP1ivrEatq4uf6HViDtyDDMCdgwNyMS/yIuWqlPIF) Works on TIO. May not work on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

## KSH script, 48 bytes

Save as a file named `k`.

```
k[1]: not: not found [No such file or directory]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P9fLzk/JVWvJDM/2jDWSiEvvwRMKKTll@alKET75SsUlyZnKKRl5qQq5BcppGQWpSaX5BdVxv7/DwA) Note that TIO saves KSH scripts as `.code.tio`, so it's a bit longer but still the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

## k, oK

Might as well group these answers together, since it's supposedly the same language. I must say, this [general approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36262/42775) is quite versatile.

#### oK

Every error seems to have a lot of environment-specific information, because, well, JavaScript is behind it all. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LboMwEEXX4SssNoCiggmEh1t1127aqB9QtZEDlkIAj2UbJfl66iYqoRCvLPucO3fqB6j7PgChA6gDePMPimRpYi30XsIRcXZEL1KCdO2Os5NghWYlKvZUUnOTyLGXmp30J/5a2o7tPVqLb8u6CATdFzzHQuZQjT52B/PrCyoVQ@6sAsm8CflEOfBzC516vvGSiebXSFYkjgZjA2XXMH9bQCuqxsS31wcDrlNMotU0@08wyzCuKuDKN/B/Lychnk5ogJZjKs7ScbqW5yv4PuXihIQ37rXjhTZThx6z3Cgjs/Vkxze04mMuwfG4pSGQuwPQSksqthzKCxXlmKQDpDSVuhP3wHCNSe71/Q8)

```
/opt/ok/oK.js:876
    throw new Error("unexpected character '"+text[0]+"'");
    ^

Error: unexpected character ')'
    at Object.parse (/opt/ok/oK.js:876:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/ok/repl.js:62:43)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

#### k

Notice the space at the bottom. This works in `2016.06.28 (c) arthur whitney` version of `kmac`.

```
a
^
value error
```

[image: Example of it working.]

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3**

```
  File ".py", line 1
    File ".py", line 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: The file must be named ".py" for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 65 bytes

```
ERROR: 'q' line 1: Empty diverts (->) are only valid on choices
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v/fNSjIP8hKQV0vOT8lVa8kM19dISczL1XB0ErBNbegpFIhJbMstaikWEFD105TIbEoVSE/L6dSoSwxJzMFyFRIzsjPTE4t5vr/HwA)

Must be saved in a file called `q`, which is why the code on TIO is 7 bytes longer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Snowman](http://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang), 121 bytes

```
SnowmanException thrown at tokenize
  what():  at tokenize: letter operator terminated prematurely?
fatal error, aborting
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcgxDsIwEETRPqeYEiROkIYqJ@AES1gSC3vXWgYZcnkTiYbuv/80b0Ws98svpveslckNXMObQQj6Qy1tOgBtFR6OI/73iKykBrxqCD2woyQT6g01tAhfoflzHu5CydAIjxPk6sFkS@9f)

Answer (score 0):

## 33

Very simple. `:` isn't a valid command, so it's easy to make an unrecognised token error quine. The error is just where the `:` is in the code.

```
33 (1:8): Unrecognised token
```

Answer (score 0):

### GNU Smalltalk REPL

[REPL is always acceptable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/when-is-code-that-requires-a-repl-acceptable), and I only learned the Smalltalk REPL and don't know how to save programs in a file. (I think TIO does not have Smalltalk yet.)

```
stdin:1: expected expression
```

This will work when you start the REPL for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

## Red 0.6.3

```
*** Error: not a Red program!
```

Newline included. Save as a `.red` file and run with `red <filename>.red`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) ([pxemi.2.min.posixism](https://github.com/GH-TpaeFawzen/pxem.posixism/blob/6ee775ef7f7a33ca42bf9ad0ecf9c533eb9f7bad/pxemi.2.min.posixism)), Filename: 14 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 14 bytes.

- Filename (has trailing LF!): `.a B4 .[wxyz]`
- Content: empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrW9rI@nt/xTAbyAwQExCrMoyuot1lV6mrbrcVqE9MQonGBEhQKNC/3vPOJIFgPc9ePkjm8t7vo22Gg@8/obeOs7u74/R3@7vm9rZl1qp3/X3TNhyrv2/tbG87d/v93TvTfhM6EdKcCZs8muEDMoxqlTnTYTCO0Fnz9ujsjDcZiWZDB31xIivw@4WC3FnB46Pp2/RAt50n3Z94HqoeFCqFQoJ8cXT9K8cKSeCQNkwJyCuqzMWnVF/GC22JU7Z/tlsfb6@uT3jVMLbTw4v3V62PZ59um@8vL0@b17zCOkjzEVbmx0dXv95@OL28ar1v14EM6hUKcyS1CtAwCN0pE5vSMVuucG5eQ3EeJ54ZOSgcCIRgGMHqORjb4dBzI2Z6rhki7QtSlXmlhJWf8VLlqviqrP3n2Vnz/ITXJQtQWjC0WThw@5FkbiMBmBw41iBAyk8UI44qgjWRJ@HAARtGQYACzz4oCC@4EapQ5jyZHsI51De90MGLxSvgKAsvJZAw00Xo2EgN9ak@01kIP191VfL9inqLBagsKQHMD2xBE7CA98T39xm4cOh6DqGkzw1mmaEDHCoYuT4i/SJFffAGc0LTYmYYOo933kw4PgCfH/lIe4omlUU0RlozREalul3bebu7t4/UTtcv9tTFl7EzRFsL8/kBqcenv7Tacw@Y2Lz2loF1yXDs@lEfqcOL4L3fdlu3VjO8evrQf@ecji@f/5p@nH36emMeRdeP5/ZJScsp@by6@A@sFYPjZgcjxUC4x7sYg0m84NkZkzAWgeC8hcuKQSnCXcwwA0OqMjQIxuWrMq5jyoTofR5yjFk/GBMGEe@5voP6Bwajc7dP0oOwwQ0q4eAwFJZsFgp9zm06PyWUSZao2Ql7bOmA15GAkrfPA@GJeH1G@lSwYy8JxzeCkHSmwZbLFZsfGUgOMcoZCSkcCIhlf@JbkRv46IxYUnYrB/LSMDKth45XKvW4lQECFAHj0XlsLuwlJvBAdU/TaHKMMEooaJVeLAYYYblUpRu0JxRA7MjIw2k8xConCh6Adn6J653n6exrT9d0Uxfq@w0j4Yy3THRcQ1sxAF5gy4RwhsDGq8iWcOBoElMxe/ohRj@DZH4JyNVBSUEykArptl4o5HyaGDI@ofMJ97UKiyXzDyZZ30oHJKLEQqBnPUBb5quyvNQlFg6biTwAIX3n/wuSqc8hQFmSPvmw2xWFL81PvCAdFJsZaV6EqqIMAaVF6gWTG@IDEaqAz2A1gAM1LILJhoFvhU/jqKcXidmo0JLeKUHaafG@SsE/zjRiS32oz4EMC6E6LMNGhcFfcjWA1QAUj/RiLmey5TzkOb3TdxJvMFMYxb3t6SXdA6rtdxqwISb4HgSwwFCdwA9BADgciEP9UdfgugKrVBa2rECGvlBze0NNdX7RcUtGjyvg11KJDTnstSpkxPAbhG@hAMzn8REfIhm5k7swGhPFKG9TZjueA93ioqNpbo/FigHiZw91PqNeSeBb@hxQCJYHCi7jAirgckzybwkogkKoz12NV1/A/h9ML8GQPNGK6T/muBY8tSKEPnhcyYsVABJkLJARg1EF03kgbAelc8imXGm/Y2jGldhdLCNEVpQhFfCBSKRpY0anJT7TyIxPKVtZ@t0VFKqI6N2Sfjgtzerg78OpBt8cfIvwzcM3P6tDU3tdpdP2yVzUnnuIvvuGy@5Lpbj8ANh9TyRG2hchy7aKiq6veoE818EgYEVdFz1TyF7UL0iBMv0L7JEOnztojzIT3FvIhb4zjh57YHm9AIVTZxFLUxqO4hoBF3Qub0xxuJRLWyxFkxMdu78aB2RTVkUWE4Oqi0W8t4H02IkmY180nphLSRAwbTvlqol9eBel@5zYw1ST7ruKOLDdp/QgLwGClECobxX1v67fEVyAGghWeSHZqhvHhfmq88AhfSDF0zY4iNugCkNClNYeVdh7sUJddQyHHNP5A@QdkOlx@BENQbjtGCgeN8QpOwbPwaJ8nADA4gVxITowoLLN2wjKHGWQ3KE1docRTwQVzc9x7G94C/rXGKZRuc32uAtyQoU@5d8J7fETKROIttnfYvPnft/ojr@tLhBcHFQyV7@vr6Q265vrjRvBVCi/vv9ILun8kgOYlETTEtejywzQhDSTrkC0SgPmh2ajuvOWHjbroqOuwH4RtMACE/@bvqULshOfTXwxe6yJJqtVkz1UjLqW1eVPwQywmpmzI3KetqWjOxjS61Aiz7MdKb7LYbbqTSvcIUlnmRyYlk7IR/jN3AfxPPH6pU9a5VH5pOytYeYjDkAwgHmO/yUakBGVsdSC5tNqcI@1IJImhJzwpIaPyq1yhdJvuGNo@z18eFKq7dVrO2L6WbFxQYYL8ssm71tyXm6Wb8qf6Pyc463bOmoHkShYzhdnjFmTAzy7AbZy@omnvtpu7J6dPXo3dswHUf2aUHdrne2dnqijN7xW05oJcgwiuj7Zi/EqNeh0Tc63RXeNgeAhFbn@xGFL4YUYutmo7QnAg51dSuWxlGHNPWZAP/FPiDQ1AGbCreyC3BQ/ZXW0Msa/INebBggzlx83UuEJ3HJf/kBl8QXTG5D391wGNzjhHmzxQaRxudVj8iNmSLG4j/f3mtbjH7IOGGdYicUYnnOB780KBZBJzFlHBG@N6wiWWKghUkGmNy2KiNlw5vM65YAcFCSAyAGJjPxT8kd5FHOErKYJdIX9IUMrDrDk8I/GKIM4@xeIB1nEryuhSIyaypWIvwKMMpYYiHq5afnH@PpBTPgDcJkAyd7bwjNZkKRtCjj2AOVlw2OyWLVEBS5BVSIidYrkXv7GdZHS2G1cggh/rlnJdiQ4/SaDB@Qsvche0aBaKxDIMGAMIJoAaxiHWqve2vCcbGAbFIsvKIqONkqqwW9JrBBpdhDZk1@eRItSRzfOOMit4mV04B2OdK/u6SNKs1yhK/5DmvlXaeaBZl7SFC3@@7v20fkpVzdeJ2/UN8337evT9jX/njQ0rEhAvEge3aj/ZvOm62OorevDhMAawXrzktSzhTTrdaQfrlb698Hmq@d3BuO/va3bl3KAhmlRXYTi/znaA6r443IlncQ@yzpcRF2yVexSBQaubkWMIHSJ4Rkj2jWXg5JmIfkPp4nI8@BRTCVwOP7hcC2mXUNau7YBIMaREO4DNHTtshO5j055aA0n5afwK7PNyKFZNWt/r2Zkuh7S/Fo1VQeUIFvd@V53KZTpVnR1/bLSqpXabm1v@21tD94g8NYBq8iZNZ5Rzfjl9u/tLN5rsZ3EB4vnXjoI4RRgxLuq@L6/vOKqmg5yIvtdmLpcMUCItxC1Om6Pr/7z0e3mA1x2IeVgpJTTVDJPjxCGeIQnnpH0@rjPx29Rtmxf5ncMziuJZiHCaTyhESAl2Mvk2uooRi@2xI8slhA3A6SF3/8H)

Answer (score 0):

## [PPL](http://pplang.expressutils.com), 79 bytes

```
Reference error on line 3, column 3

  a()
  ^

The identifier a is not defined
```

I haven't implemented syntax checking properly, so only reference errors and type errors are thrown (plus syntax checking in rare cases). Pretty simple answer, frankly. Attempts to call the nonexisting `a` function (just `a` without the call does not work because my interpreter does not check for invalid expressions in some cases) I know my language is not very good but I'm too lazy to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

## Snap! (scratchblocks syntax)

```
Hmm...
a custom block definition is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript

Thought I would make an updated JS answer.

Firefox:

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
```

Google Chrome:

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'SyntaxError'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Applescript, 70 bytes

`0:2: syntax error: A “:” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)`

Run with `osascript -e "0:2: syntax error: A “:” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)"`

Answer (score 0):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 43 bytes

```
.code.tio:1: unknown token at: .code.tio:1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/Xw9E6ZVk5lsZWimU5mXn5ZfnKZTkZ6fmKSSWWCkgS///DwA)

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org/), 95 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__IyBTaW5nbGUtYnl0ZSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgc2V0IChTQkNTKQojIGZvciBVaXVhIDAuOS4wLCB3cml0dGVuIGluIFVpdWEgMC45LjAKIyBXcml0dGVuIGhhc3RpbHkgYW5kIG1haW50YWluZWQgaW5mcmVxdWVudGx5CiMgYnkgVG9ieSBCdXNpY2stV2FybmVyLCBAVGJ3IG9uIFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlCiMgQ3JlYXRlZCAyNyBEZWNlbWJlciAyMDIzIAojIFVwZGF0ZWQgMTcgRmVicmFyeSAyMDI0CgojIEFTQ0lJIGlzIGNvbXB1dGVkIGRpcmVjdGx5LCBidXQgaWYgbW9yZSBzcGFjZSBpcyBuZWVkZWQsCiMgbW9zdCBvZiB0aGUgY29udHJvbCBjb2RlcyBjYW4gYmUgcmVwbGFjZWQuCgpBU0NJSSDihpAgKyBAXDAg4oehMTI4CgojIEFsbCBvZiBVaXVhJ3MgZ2x5cGhzLiAKIyBJbmNsdWRlcyBkZXByZWNhdGVkIGdseXBocyDijIXiiqDiip3iipDiipTii5Tiqr7ihqzihqssCiMgYXMgdGhleSBzdGlsbCB3b3JrIGFzIG9mIEZlYnJ1YXJ5IDE3LgoKVUlVQSDihpAgIuKXjOKImMKswrHCr-KMteKImuKXi-KMiuKMiOKBheKJoOKJpOKJpcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDihILip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3CpOKLr-KNieKNj-KNluKKmuKKm-KKneKXtOKXsOKWoeKLleKJjeKKn-KKguKKj-KKoeKGr-KYh-KGmeKGmOKGu-KXq-KWveKMleKIiuKKl-KIp-KIteKJoeKKnuKKoOKNmuKNpeKKleKKnOKKkOKKlOKXh-KLheKKmeKfnOKIqc67wrDijIXijZziioPiqr7iipPii5TijaLirJrijaPijaTihqzihqvimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ7iuK7ihpDigLwiCgojIEFsbCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIFVpdWEgdXNlcyBmb3IgcHJldHR5LXByaW50aW5nLgojIENhbiBiZSByZW1vdmVkIGlmIG5lY2Vzc2FyeS4KCkRSQVdJTkcg4oaQICLila3ilIDilbfila_in6bin6fijJzijJ_ilZPilZ_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-KXi-KIqSjDtzI1KeKHoTI0MOKHoTgwIgojIEVuY29kZSB0byBhIC5zYmNzIGZpbGU6CiMgICBFbmNvZGVVQSBQYXRoVUEKIyBEZWNvZGUgYSAuc2JjcyBmaWxlOgojICAgRGVjb2RlU0JDUyBQYXRoU0JDUwo=)</sup>

```
Error: Unexpected token |
  at 1:25
1 | Error: Unexpected token |
                            ─
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RXJyb3I6IFVuZXhwZWN0ZWQgdG9rZW4gfAogIGF0IDE6MjUKMSB8IEVycm9yOiBVbmV4cGVjdGVkIHRva2VuIHwKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIOKUgAo=)

Answer (score 0):

## YASEPL

```
ERROR 5 no variable is loaded:(

located at :
```

very simple

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 99 bytes code + 8 bytes file path, 107 bytes

File must be named `>>;/\1/a` to close off the `<-- HERE ... <-- HERE` and to reference the nonexistent group in a regex.

Link is to a Bash test suite.

```perl
Reference to nonexistent group in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\1 <-- HERE / at >>;/\1/a line 1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHLboMwEEX3fMVdNSsKtrENDWIXqeus2fAYUpRAIkIkKvXf6ZjQlyq1RhoN9tzj65myuL7Mc3es2wH@BXnG3zbIc@FNUw1/QPZtLyiQpik24bqeoKXRMIaDXTIyCkbLEDYyDWRoCKbhgD01NFBfEcYz@nPv3QmCGUbbGCaxyokcw0ZOaR2ygdU2dL8JQFN7HakfcRjOtwvalSEdg9ydiwXrzMSqdKIaRlgJU7qDiEvQY6ADTVt0xXCkGitDOYa0CYtUBVnLmrMoRqS15MBKk/AzFiTKV6S@j@fdfoe2R7cyImbIRldQgutV5Rg1Z1EcaW4UBxnKpSkCCHLxBQlQrAzNDOuMKlIEVXK9rpRgLotYWd19LC3GiCzjubixnNqePt5imMEWCGGBf5d4fNx43oWG0485e1Ux/r2BN3S1vt6632LI7EF8ns/zOw)