# Case invert your quine

Tags: string, code-challenge, quine

Write a quine which attempts to invert the case of as many ascii characters in the source code as possible. For example in javascript:

```
(x=function(y){return ('(x='+y+')(x)').toUpperCase();})(x)
```

- Standard quine rules apply.
- The score is given by *number of bytes in the source code* - *number of case inversions*. For example, the quine above has a score of 29.
- The program with the lowest score wins. If two programs have the same score then the shorter one wins.

Comment: So non-letters count as 1 byte each no matter what, because they cannot be case-inverted? (Also, please use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) next time.)

Comment: Yes they do. The challenge is to try to make as much of the program change as possible. Sorry for not using the sandbox. It wasn't letting me post in there for some reason (maybe not enough rep?)

Comment: Does the output program have to be a valid program in the language? (The output of your example quine doesn't really work as a valid program.)

Comment: @petStorm no the output doesn't have to be valid.

Comment: `invert the case of as many ascii characters` Does that mean that if a unicode character has its case inverted complement, we aren't expected to count that unicode character if we invert it in our output?

Comment: Hmm, so theoretically you could get a negative score if you found a language that encoded letters in less than a byte?

Comment: Variant: the result also has to be a case-inverting quine.

Comment: If not for standard quine rules, a one-character Text program has a pretty good score.

Comment: @petStorm I think the simplest criteria is that the source code and the output are treated as ascii bytes (with invalid bytes allowed) but I am open to changing this if there's a good argument against it. Maybe it should be *number of code points* - *number of [a-zA-Z] (as code points) cases inverted*?

I'm new to this website. I'm not sure if I could even change the challenge now, or if I'm allowed to be this indecisive about your questions.

Comment: @JoKing See my answer to petStorm. Negative scores should be impossible imo.

Comment: I think the fact that your code can be as long as you like, if it's made out of only letters, is the biggest unintended feature. This is why there's a sandbox.

Comment: @user253751 Code golf is secondary winning criterion (so currently `Gol><>` wins over `><>`). OP didn't have access to the sandbox when they wrote the challenge (see OP's first comment).

Answer (score 29):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), score 479 - 479 = 0

```
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllbfppllfepeeppppgglcepppbeppppppppppplfdppedpddpgglcdppbdpfcpecpggldcppllccpbcpplfbpebppldbppcbpggcbglefgpgbeglefgpgcbglefgpgggggedglefgpgccglefgpgfdglefgpgebglefgpgecglefgpggdcglefgpgceglefgpgeeglefgpgbcglefgpgfbglefgpgcdgfefgpbdgeefgpfegdefgpccgcefgpfdgbefgpdbgaefgpppddglefgpgbcglefgpgfcglefgpgdbglefgpgdcglefgpgecglefgpgddglefgpgdbglefgplffpbfgffgefgpcbgefgefgp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY@7jkMxCES/dYdhSCQXSPl/ecG6uEkfCs/hjfX@vPZevzcocy15umdZxLIGHO@xJWY6kzz5csCUpVv7tJ5glmgQ0lHKegyVN8RyRQb8gRtpc07UHtBEfOp8UsEhm2E@gNs/bcZQA1hVpfJga22y47NuKiXirzXrg1/DBjhT7wn3qts1NUtKKKQ469DStPc/)

#### How it works

Very few useful instructions in ><> are letters.
However, we still have the `l`, pushing the length of the stack to the stack. As such, it's possible to (very verbosely) push arbitrary values to the stack. Thus, strings can be encoded in a similar fashion to brainfuck, using `a` to increase the length of the stack, and `g` or `p` to reduce it.

As per usual quine rules, `g` is not used to read the source code itself, instead maintaining registers at locations such as`bb` and `bc` and so on.

The string encoded is the prefix:

`"r&:20&3-:&?.p48*-od0l2)?.;lllll"]"`

Which after over 7,000 instructions outputs the original string in upper case.

Comment: @JoKing Made a better encoding, where your version performs better.

Answer (score 10):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), <s>77</s> 75 - 75 = 0

```
urassssissezplzelssmzmzpssazmkqjmkrmbrrrrrtsuotlballsssssassmzpsssssbssmzpu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBEsAgCMTeCjO2VWG0rlz4PC3mlENyD7kqnghbhJ8KFJ/iRQB19QmQa3@b9qW8kg0bW5hEcgBlOI/yUYv4AA)

Based on [Bubbler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209774/76162), this goes even further by also putting the `"` at the start of the code to get a score of `0`!

#### Explanation

```
ur       Move over one on the stack tape and reverse the stack
  assssissez      Push 10+16*4=74,-1+16*2=31,!(15)=0
            p     And put the 74 (J) at position 0,31

lz            Push 0 if there is anything on the stack
  e           Push 14 for later
   lssmzmz    Push 2+16*2=34, !(-1)=0, !(-1)=0
          p   Put the 34 (") at position 0,0

sss           Add 3*16 to the -1 from earlier
   az         Push !(10)=0
     mkq      Some no-ops
        J     And jump to 0,47 if the stack was initially empty

lballsssssassmzp  Put T at position 0,43
sssssbssmzpu      Put S at position 0,44
u                 Move one over on the stack again (effectively resetting the stack)

"                 Wrap, pushing everything to the stack
 r                Reverse
  .........       Put everything again
           J      But this time don't jump, since the stack is not empty

mk           Copy the bottom of the stack (u)
  rm         Push a -1 to the bottom of the stack
    brrrrr   No-ops

T   t      Finally, loop over the stack, 
 Suo       Capitalising then outputting everything until we get to the -1
```

Comment: The arithmetic reads almost like "ur ass plz"...

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys You may like my most recent golf

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys New challenge idea: a quine (or something else) which is also a valid English sentence.

Comment: @user253751 [Similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47091/76162)

Comment: Yes, like that, but stricter: grammar and punctuation must also be valid for English. (I'm not sure if that would even be solvable; I suspect it would in at least one language, but it might be very long)

Answer (score 10):

### 80186+ machine code (MS-DOS .COM format), 115-115=0

It was a bit tricky to do this, as I only had access to `INC`, `DEC`, `PUSH`, certain `POP` variations, `POPA`, `IMUL`, and certain conditional jumps. Fortunately, `IMUL` could do the heavy lifting for this challenge!

I encoded the actual code that does the printing in a series of values that get multiplied together. I compute those values (which get truncated to 16-bit values), store them on the stack which I moved to be just above the code, and then jump to the generated code to print the program's code in the opposite case.

Machine code:

```
hrXhCNhGUhnPhPwhYkhvLhKwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaPQRjZTUVjfaiQVGARiQSCARiQPQARiQMJARiQJZARiQGuARiQDkARiQAWARpI
```

Assembler source:

```
IDEAL
P186

MODEL   TINY
CODESEG
ORG 100H

MAIN:
        ; Encoded code:
        ;   MOV SI,100H
        ;   MOV CX,73H
        ; PRINT:
        ;   LODSB
        ;   XOR AL,20H
        ;   INT 29H
        ;   NOP
        ;   LOOP PRINT
        ;   INT 20H
               ; Offset Bytes Multiplier
    PUSH 5872H ; +41    BE 00 4157H
    PUSH 4E43H ; +44    01 B9 416BH
    PUSH 5547H ; +47    73 00 4175H
    PUSH 506EH ; +4A    AC 34 415AH
    PUSH 7750H ; +4D    20 CD 414AH
    PUSH 6B59H ; +50    29 90 4151H
    PUSH 4C76H ; +53    E2 F8 4143H
    PUSH 774BH ; +56    CD 20 4147H

REPT 30
    POPA ; Adjust stack to point to end of generated code
ENDM

    PUSH AX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH DX
    PUSH 5AH
    PUSH SP
    PUSH BP
    PUSH SI
    PUSH 66H
    POPA ; Use POPA as POP DX and POP DI are not in [A-Za-z]
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+56H],4147H
    PUSH DX
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+53H],4143H
    PUSH DX
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+50H],4151H
    PUSH DX
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+4DH],414AH
    PUSH DX
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+4AH],415AH
    PUSH DX
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+47H],4175H
    PUSH DX
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+44H],416BH
    PUSH DX
    IMUL DX,[BX+DI+41H],4157H
    PUSH DX
    JO $+4BH ; Jump to start of generated code

END MAIN
ENDS
```

Comment: Would it be too restrictive to use only one case (upper or lower)?

Comment: @Bubbler: Probably uppercase-only would work, but it would be quite lengthy, as only INC, DEC, PUSH, POP and POPA would be available. I'll try that approach, though, and see if I can get it to work!

Comment: Sounds impossible if you don't have jumps (unless you can somehow force the memory layout to work without jumps...)

Comment: @Bubbler: You can either write a long enough program that enters the stack normally, or adjust the stack with POPA by underflowing the stack!

Answer (score 8):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), score 34 - 33 = 1

```
"mrllssslssscsmzpdsmzprrrrrrtsuota
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/Xym3KCenuLgYhJOLc6sKUkBEERiUFJfmlyT@/w8A)

Outputs the following and exits by error, which is every char uppercased except the leading `"`.

```
"MRLLSSSLSSSCSMZPDSMZPRRRRRRTSUOTA
```

#### How it works

The lines marked with `*` are the differences from the previous version.

```
"..."    Push every char except `"`
mrl      Push -1, reverse stack, push stack length (34 = `"`)
* lsss   Push stack length (35) and add 16 three times (83 = S)
* lsss   Push stack length (36) and add 16 three times (84 = T)
* csmzp  Push 13, add 16 (29), push -1, boolean negate (0), and
         replace the command at (29,0) by T
* dsmzp  Push 14, add 16 (30), push -1, boolean negate (0), and
         replace the command at (30,0) by S
* rrrrrr  Reverse the stack 6 times;
          no-op to move the positions to overwrite
TSuot    Infinite uppercase-print loop; halt by error at -1
a        Not executed
```

---

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), score 34 - 31 = 3

```
"mrlTSuotaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/Xym3KCckuDS/JBEX@P8fAA)

Outputs the following and exits by error.

```
"MRLTSUOTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Every lowercase letters are uppercased, so the only chars that are not modified are `"TS`.

#### How it works

```
"..."  Start string literal, push every char in the source code (except `"`),
       wrap around and end string literal
mr     Push -1 and reverse the stack
       (setup the chars for printing from top, and bury the trap at the bottom)
l      Push length of stack, which gives 34 == `"`
T...t  Infinite loop until it errors in the middle:
 Su     Uppercase the char at the top (errors when trying to uppercase -1)
 o      Pop and print as char
a...   Not reached
```

<s>I suspect 2 or lower might be possible.</s>

Comment: You can probably get `0` through some careful `p`utting and `J`umping?

Comment: [Like this!](https://tio.run/##LYtJDsAwCAPfmlZKN1AQDhc@T6DtnDyWfQzqF84I04aEgeZCzpTZ2UUVVd38KOvHhI1JSR2w11B@2V6xiAU)

Comment: @JoKing Wow, awesome. You definitely should post it as your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), score 3

```
2i2I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yjTyPP/fwA)

4 bytes with 1 case inversion. Twice inserts (`2i`) the string `2I`.

Comment: You need an escape character at the end for this to work. What you have now just writes `2I`. `<esc>` completes the `i` insert so the initial `2` can be used to double the insertion to `2I2I`.

Comment: @Noodle9 In vim, yes, but this is V. V escapes implicitly at the end.

Comment: Oh, didn't realise there's a language V, will check it out - thanks! :-)

Comment: You could get a slightly better score if unicode characters were allowed to be lowercased: `ñéÑ"qpxVUllvulllllvlu` would have a score of 1 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///DGwysPT1QqLKgIC83JKSvNAYGynNL//wE "V (vim) – Try It Online")

Comment: @James Cool! If Unicode characters end up being allowed then you should definitely post your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), score <sup><s>24</s> <s>20</s> <s>16</s> <s>12</s></sup> 11

*Saved a byte thanks to a comment by @Sisyphus on another answer.*

```ruby
eval S="print'EVAL s=%p'%S.swapcase"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P7UsMUch2FapoCgzr0TdNczRR6HYVrVAXTVYr7g8sSA5sThV6f9/AA)

36 bytes with 25 case inversions. The case of every letter is changed in the output.

Answer (score 5):

## 05AB1E, 16 - 6 = 10

```
0"D34çýu"D34çýu
```

(trailing newline)

## Explanation

```
0"D34çýu"D34çýu # full code
0"D34çý "D34çý  # standard 05AB1E quine
       u      u # uppercase string in stack
                # implicit print
```

Not the *best* golf, but it is my *first* golf so have mercy please.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7S@EMrv//AQ)

---

## 05AB1E (legacy), 16 - 8 = 8

```
0"D34çýš"D34çýš
```

(trailing newline)

## Explanation

```
0"D34çýu"D34çýu # full code
0"D34çý "D34çý  # standard 05AB1E quine
       š      š # switch case builtin
                # implicit print
```

Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for -2 score.
Doesnt work with current 05AB1E becuase the switch case function is `.š` which makes the byte count larger

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7jy5EsLj@/wcA)

Comment: Too bad `.š` (switch case builtin) only works on ASCII letters `a-zA-Z` in the new version of 05AB1E. You can however improve your score by switching to the older legacy version of 05AB1E, and use `š` instead of `u`: [`0"D34çýš"D34çýš`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7jy5EsLj@/wcA), which also switches the unicode letters `çýš`. Btw, I think your current score is actually 16-2=14, since only the two `u` are `U` in your output, and everything else is the same. The new score would become 16-8=8. Nice first answer regardless, and welcome to CGCC! :)

Comment: The output on TIO for me is 0"D34ÇÝU"D34ÇÝU...
Does the ÇÝ case inversion not count?
Also, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Ah sorry, I saw it incorrectly. It does indeed count. I thought `u` only worked with ASCII letters, but apparently I was mistaken. You can still lower your score by 2 by changing the language to `05AB1E (legacy)` and changing both `u` to `š`, which is the switch-case builtin. :) In the new 05AB1E version this would be `.š` instead, which make the byte-count larger.

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), Score = <s>3</s> 2

```
foccmawSeohs"foccmawseohs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py0/OTk3sTw4NT@jWAnKKQZx/v8HAA)

So many letters!

Thanks Dominic van Essen for -1 to the score.

#### Explanation

The standard quine in Husk is `S+s"S+s"`: it takes the string `S+s`, and concatenates it with its version surrounded by quotes. The swapcase command `\` would be easy to add here, but being an escape character as well it needs to be doubled inside the quoted string, resulting in too many unswappable character for my tastes.

What we do instead is convert each character to uppercase (with the conveniently lowercase builtin `a`), and then we just need to make sure to use only lowercase letters as much as possible. We can get rid of a final `"` by using `h` (init) on the quoted string, then the rest of the code is devoted to getting rid of that `+` symbol to concatenate strings.

```
foccmawSeohs"foccmawseohs
            "foccmawseohs    A string
       Se                    put it in a 2-elements list
         ohs                 with the quoted version of itself, minus the last quote
      w                      Join the two strings with a space
    ma                       Convert each character to uppercase
f                            And keep only those characters that are truthy when...
 occ                          converted to charcode and back
```

The last part is just an identity function (but `I` would be uppercase), and spaces are falsy in Husk, so we are just keeping all non-space characters in the string.

I'd love to get rid of the `S` but I don't see how, and I don't think it is possible to have a quine without quotes, barring convoluted conversions from numbers that would score terribly in this challenge... (Prove me wrong and you get a bounty!)

Comment: Easy [score of 2](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py0/OTk3sTw4NT@jWAnKKQZx/v8HAA) by lowercasing the second capital "S"...

Comment: Yeah, one would have to be pretty dumb to miss that :D

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 - 38 = 32

```javascript
f=x=>`f=${f}`.replace(/(.)/g,y=>y<'`'?y.toLowerCase():y.toUpperCase())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LCsIwFET3fkUFwYTG1HXxVtCtO3GlxcT0plVKUpr6iKXfXisoiMsZhjnnIm/SqfpcNTNjM@x7DQ9IhIZJqzvBa6xKqZBEhNMoZx4Sv5iK6dLzxm7sHeu1dEho/M67qvpm2itrnC2RlzYnDjShTByMoKPfXqx8gy4OgmDSnsDxEk3eFN3/al1Ik2MWByLcc84HNxHqdFDLroMZOTLPnhQSFYIfg9s/U6ZgTv9OtsrW@EHN1MDoXw)

BTW: This is my first contribution and I'm a bit confused. I made sure to swap every possible character. The example only uppercases. If you don't *need* to actually swap cases, then one can get 11-0=11 with a simplified variant of an answer given above:

```javascript
f=x=>"f="+f
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC and congratulations on a great first answer!  You're right that there's no requirement to change all (or any) of the cases, so your second 'simple quine' indeed beats the first one according to the scoring system.  However, you can  improve your score by at least swapping one character: ```f=x=>"F="+f```` scores 10 (since the first 'f' changes case)...

Comment: Woah, good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), Score 52 - 33 = 19

```python
s='S=%r;PRINT S%%S.SWAPCASE()';print s%s.swapcase()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWPdhWtcg6IMjTL0QhWFU1WC843DHA2THYVUNT3bqgKDOvRKFYtVivuDyxIDmxOFVDk@v/fwA)

Case inverts every letter in the quine.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 37 bytes, 20 swapped case, Score 17

Thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen) for -1!

```perl
eval($a=q{print uc"eval(\$a=q{$a})"})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHQyXRtrC6oCgzr0ShNFkJLBQDFlNJrNVUqtX8/x8A)

Comment: [Rearranged a bit](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHQyXRtrC6oCgzr0ShNFkJLBQDFlNJrNVUqtX8/x8A) to get 37 with 20 swapped = score 17.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice one, thank you! I was hoping to get something working with: [the `printf+qw()x2` approach, but `%S` doesn't work...](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1bozRZu1ADhaNarKlZYQTC//8DAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") Also looked as using letters as delimeters (`q z...z`) but the nesting is problematic, didn't think to rearrange though... :)

Comment: Are you sure?  I still [count](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jnq/4/tSwxR0Ml0bawuqAoM69EoTRZobBQoQosHAMWV0ms1ayq1fyvbs0FUaIB1FinH52oW@WoGxWrn66JJhGHJPMfAA) 17 non-letter characters...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen that'll teach me to count the chars in a browser window, `\$` doesn't count :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), score 4

```
`④`④
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/4dHExSD8/z8A)

4 bytes with 0 case conversions.

The standard quine without case conversion easily beats any Keg approaches that would have case conversion: by the time you've thrown case conversion techniques into the mix, you might as well have just written a standard quine with no fancy details.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), score = 78 - 53 = 25

```r
a='a=%s;cat(toupper(sprintf(a,squote(a))))';cat(toupper(sprintf(a,sQuote(a))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfmVeWWZyZlJOqEVxZrFecWpKTn5wI5CUnlqSm5xdVKtgqKPk4xzv6@CjpKEDkQELOSpqa/xNt1RNtVYutgWo1SvJLCwpSizSKC4oy80rSNBJ1igtL80tSNRI1gUAdl5pAhJr//wE)

Comment: I think there is an issue with the quotes: the source code uses quotation marks (U+0022) but `sQuote` gives "fancy" single quotation marks (U+2018 and U+2019). Using `dQuote(a,F)` instead works on my computer (at a cost of +3 points), but not on TIO for some reason.

Comment: @RobinRyder - I think this is an effect of the default locale configured on TIO: I've added a header to reset to the less-'fancy' 'C' locale for everything, and it now seems to work (as it does on my own local R instance).  Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Looks good now. BTW, congrats on 10k rep!

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 27 - 13 = 14

```
f=x=>`f=${f}`.toUpperCase()
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##Xc2xDoIwFIXh3aeoCUMbSuNMchnkEYwTElvLLWpIS2g1AuHZK4ODYT35c76neiuvh0cfMusajNHABwppIJnNIkVw577HoVQeKYvaWe86FJ1rqQdDGZcXK9nuf5fHMaDPCSHJfAMvOrRtuC/bqrwr22KTE5lWQogVlKmpxYDNSyOlVz7yiUGhUxj34Kup5hoObHNy0m7AH5Xp1Yhf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes − 8 inversions = score 2

```
`NDqp`NDqp
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60NDqp%60NDqp&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), Score = <s>very big number - very big number</s> 4508 - 4508 = 0

```
XaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXODTnBsbRvTTTTngmngmnngmngDUTnBsTTnnngmgTnBsTTTngmnnnngmgDVTnBsTTTnnngmngmngTnBsYTnBsTXmRykTnBXaKsYTnBsJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVfBCoMwDP230dN2KIgb2VFhyBi6gzDY13dat5OOtu8liliNaUzavJf4HJv2fgtBGu@8@Dj49cP6uqW7OfzXS3wt12iWsbRJyY2ryO3CD@bZBtcg7VmmNh90cTip2ULsPGAHwUNZCGVzFRIacyzXCxOeQHCpAFLBU1Lw1MW2GPebZASIfHGU26QyTDd7@UHUFaEzkqVPanmIpVNoD0xJAkabVXHli4FyxTZxFbFGpDNNbzg8DaorFDXdUJvzJgcirT8FnVJt@CsiWnkOgE9UcVvWs2nTMVLGFBpxGm1i1TnKzh1hYdSuHg5jW73q6Ri6fj7j4M7zi0k2P3bLfVRYBO7yEw3fWVHnGqXSV@/HdCfNaZEcQ/gA)

EDIT: Can now finish in the lifetime of the universe!

Explaination:

```
XaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXOXaODOXOXaODOOXaODOXO
            pushes 395523372811533155555555231622231622232316222316395655233728555523232316221655233728555555231622232323231622163957552337285555552323231622231622231655233728605523372855592253342055233759104628605523372845
D           duplicate it
TnB         and convert one of the duplicated to base 10^2 = 100, which is this code case inverted
s           swap, moving to front the number
b           convert it to binary
R           and reverse the binary
v           for each digit
 TTTT       push 10,10,10,10^1
 n          square, 10,10,10,10^2
 g          length, 10, 10, 10, 3
 m          exponent, 10,10,10^3
 n          square, 10,10,10^6
 gm         10^length, 10,10^7
 n          square, 10, 10^14
 n          square, 10, 10^28
 gm         10^length, 10^29
 n          square, 10^58
 g          59
 DU         duplicate and save in variable X
 TnB        convert to base 100, "x"
 s          and swap, so the stack is "x", "<string>"
 TTnnngmg   push 10, in the same way as 59
 TnBs       convert from base 100 and swap, so the stack is "x", "A", "<string>"
 TTTngmnnnngmg  push 50, in the same way as 59 and 10
 DV          save in variable Y
 TnBs       convert from base 100 and swap, so the stack is "x", "A", "o", "<string>"
 TTTnnngmngmng  push 39
 TnBs      convert from base 100 and swap, so the stack is "x", "A", "o", "d", "<string>"
 Y         push variable Y, 50
 TnBs      convert from base 100 and swap, "x", "A", "o", "d", "o", "<string>"
 TXmRyk    X if the current bit is 0, else 0
 TnBXaK    convert from base 100 and remove zeros, "X" if the value is 0 else ""
 sYTnBs    add "o" again
 J         join everything
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 44 - 25 = 19 bytes

SwapCase all the char of the quine leaving only the non-alpha chars unchanged

```python
exec(a:="input('EXEC(A:=%r)'%a.swapcase())")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWKTOvoLREQ901wtVZw9HKVrVIU101Ua@4PLEgObE4VUNTU0nz/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), score 16 - 6 = 10

Sadly, a [standard quine with no toggling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71932/16484) scores the same (10 bytes), but this is way more fun. Every letter is toggled.

```js
"i34d¹²u"i34d¹²u 
"i34d¹²u"        // Take this string, shortly just the program string after the quote
         i       // Prepend
          34d    // a quote char,
             ¹   // and then (closing parens)
              ²u // repeat the result twice and uppercase it.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ImkzNGS5snUiaTM0ZLmydQ==&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 29

```hs
import Data.Char;main=putStr x>>print x;x=map toUpper"import data.char;main=putstr x>>print x;x=map toupper"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzzkjscg6NzEzz7agtCS4pEihws6uoCgzr0ShwrrCNjexQKEkP7SgILVICaorBaQrGVlXMXZdpWBdXP//AwA)

The non-flipped bytes are:

```hs
 D.C;=S >> ;= U" .;= >> ;= "
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 - 27 = 16 bytes

```python
a="print'A=%r;EXEC A'%a.swapcase()";exec a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWqaAoM69E3dFWtcjaNcLVWcFRXTVRr7g8sSA5sThVQ1PJOrUiNVkhkev/fwA)

Same answer than my Python 3 solution ... but ths time I can remove the parenthesis of the `exec` function and the `print` function (costing one char for the trailing newline)